# checking for NULL before calling free

Tags: c, allocation

Many C code freeing pointers calls:

```
if (p)
  free(p);
```

But why? I thought C standard say the `free` function doesn't do anything given a NULL pointer. So why another explicit check?

Comment: Because people don't know the C standard?

Comment: Duplicate, ish of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/615355/is-there-any-reason-to-check-for-a-null-pointer-before-deleting

Comment: WaffleMatt: that is about C++ (and no C++ tag :-(   ) - my is C, so it's a bit different. C++ is newer so maybe 'old habits' have less traction there

Comment: That's where the "ish" is.  So I should say, that article may also be of interest even if it isn't a duplicate.

Comment: @zaharpopov: I added c++ to 615355.

Comment: Waffle: OK, sorry my bad english - didn know what "ish" means

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The construct:

```
free(NULL);
```

has always been OK in C, back to the original UNIX compiler written by Dennis Ritchie. Pre-standardisation, some poor compilers might not have fielded it correctly, but these days any compiler that does not cannot legitimately call itself a compiler for the C language. Using it typically leads to clearer, more maintainable code.

Answer (score 17):

As I understand, the no-op on NULL was not always there.

> In the bad old days of C (back around
>   1986, on a pre-ANSI standard cc
>   compiler) free(NULL) would dump core. 
>   So most devs tested for NULL/0 before
>   calling free.
>
> The world has come a long way, and it
>   appears that we don't need to do the
>   test anymore.  But old habits die
>   hard;)

http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?design.4.194233.15

Comment: +1 This is what I remember but I couldn't find the reference to it.

Comment: As I understand it, this flaw existed in some compilers even after standardization.

Comment: It was always there, even in the original UNIX implementation. This is mentioned in P.J. Plauger's article on the standardisation process - can't find exact  reference at this moment though.

Comment: THe day that Joel is quoted as  a technical authority is a sad one for the human race.

Comment: Neil: this is quote from the forum on joel website, actual quote not from him but someone named Guidii. so i think human race has been saved today

Comment: Reciting Joel's uncited urban legend does not make a valid answer.

Comment: I wonder whether the requirement that `free(NULL)` does nothing ties in with the fact that `malloc(0)` is allowed to return `NULL`.  IMHO, `malloc(0)` should have been allowed to return null on those systems, and only on those systems, where adding or subtracting integer `0` to/from a null pointer yields a null pointer (rather than UB), and `free(0)` does nothing, but having `free(0)` be safe on other systems isn't so important.

Answer (score 11):

I tend to write "`if (p) free(p)`" a lot, even if I know it's not needed.

I partially blame myself because I learned C the old days when `free(NULL)` would segfault and I still feel uncomfortable not doing it.

But I also blame the C standard for not being consistent. Would, for example, fclose(NULL) be well defined, I would not have problems in writing:

```
free(p);
fclose(f);
```

Which is something that happens very often when cleaning up things.
Unfortunately, it seems strange to me to write

```
free(p);
if (f) fclose(f);
```

and I end up with

```
if (p) free(p);
if (f) fclose(f);
```

I know, it's not a rational reason but that's my case :)

Comment: Yes, this answer pin points the lack of consistency in C and it is in fact overhead on the programmer to track the proper practices.

Answer (score 2):

Compilers, even when inlining are not smart enough to know the function will return immediately. Pushing parameters etc on stack and setting the call up up is obviously more expensive than testing a pointer. I think it is always good practice to avoid execution of anything, even when that anything is a no-op.
Testing for null is a good practice. An even better practice is to ensure your code does not reach this state and therefore eliminate the need for the test altogether.

Comment: It's no longer obvious in the face of mis-predicted branches.

Comment: *Pushing parameters etc on stack* Compilers didn't do that even in 2013.

Answer (score 2):

There are two distinct reasons why a pointer variable could be NULL:

1. because the variable is used for what in type theory is called an *option type*, and holds either a pointer to an object, or NULL to represent *nothing*,
2. because it points to an array, and may therefore be NULL if the array has zero length (as `malloc(0)` is allowed to return NULL, implementation-defined).

Although this is only a logical distinction (in C there are neither *option types* nor special *pointers to arrays* and we just use pointers for everything), it should always be made clear how a variable is used.

That the C standard requires `free(NULL)` to do nothing is the necessary counterpart to the fact that a successful call to `malloc(0)` may return `NULL`. It is not meant as a general convenience, which is why for example `fclose()` *does* require a non-NULL argument. Abusing the permission to call `free(NULL)` by passing a NULL that does not represent a zero-length array feels hackish and wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> if (p)
>     free(p);
> ```
>
> why another explicit check?

If *I* write something like that, it's to convey the specific knowledge that the pointer may be NULL...to assist in readability and code comprehension.  Because it looks a bit weird to make that an assert:

```
assert(p || !p);
free(p);
```

*(Beyond looking strange, compilers are known to complain about "condition always true" if you turn your warnings up in many such cases.)*

So I see it as good practice, if it's not clear from the context.

The converse case, of a pointer being expected to be *non* null, is usually evident from the previous lines of code:

```
...
Unhinge_Widgets(p->widgets);
free(p); // why `assert(p)`...you just dereferenced it!
...
```

But if it's non-obvious, having the assert may be worth the characters typed.

Answer (score -1):

there can be a custom implementation of free() in mobile environment.
In that case free(0) can cause a problem.
(yeah, bad implementation)

Comment: A new C implementation, when started today, has no excuse for producing such a bug. The C standards are clear in that point.

Comment: @vog: Freestanding implementations aren't required to provide `malloc()` and `free()` at all, but will typically allow user code to define such functions as they see fit.  Including an explicit null-check will make code work even in the presence of `#define free(x) customReleaseThatDoesntLikeNull(x)`.