# C read file line by line

Tags: c, file-io, line, libc

I wrote this function to read a line from a file:

```
const char *readLine(FILE *file) {

    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Error: file pointer is null.");
        exit(1);
    }

    int maximumLineLength = 128;
    char *lineBuffer = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * maximumLineLength);

    if (lineBuffer == NULL) {
        printf("Error allocating memory for line buffer.");
        exit(1);
    }

    char ch = getc(file);
    int count = 0;

    while ((ch != '\n') && (ch != EOF)) {
        if (count == maximumLineLength) {
            maximumLineLength += 128;
            lineBuffer = realloc(lineBuffer, maximumLineLength);
            if (lineBuffer == NULL) {
                printf("Error reallocating space for line buffer.");
                exit(1);
            }
        }
        lineBuffer[count] = ch;
        count++;

        ch = getc(file);
    }

    lineBuffer[count] = '\0';
    char line[count + 1];
    strncpy(line, lineBuffer, (count + 1));
    free(lineBuffer);
    const char *constLine = line;
    return constLine;
}
```

The function reads the file correctly, and using printf I see that the constLine string did get read correctly as well.

However, if I use the function e.g. like this:

```
while (!feof(myFile)) {
    const char *line = readLine(myFile);
    printf("%s\n", line);
}
```

printf outputs gibberish. Why?

Comment: Use `fgets` instead of `fgetc`. You are reading character by character instead of line by line.

Comment: Note that [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) is a part of POSIX 2008.  There may be POSIX-like platforms without it, especially if they don't support the rest of POSIX 2008, but within the world of POSIX systems, `getline()` is pretty portable these days.

Comment: line[count+1] is an automatic stack variable and you use a pointer to it as return value. This is UB.

Answer (score 425):

If your task is not to invent the line-by-line reading function, but just to read the file line-by-line, you may use a typical code snippet involving the `getline()` function (see the manual page [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getline)):

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE * fp;
    char * line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;

    fp = fopen("/etc/motd", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
        printf("Retrieved line of length %zu:\n", read);
        printf("%s", line);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    if (line)
        free(line);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: More precisely, this `getline` is specific to GNU libc, i.e., to Linux. However, if the intent is to have a line-reading function (as opposed to learning C), there are several public domain line-reading functions available on the web.

Comment: also i think you wanna `free(line)` before the end of that while loop

Comment: Why should I do that? Read the manual, buffer is reallocated at each call, then it should be freed at the end.

Comment: The `if(line)` check is superfluous.  Calling `free(NULL)` is essentially a no-op.

Comment: @aroth I agree, but this is an excerpt from the `man` page. "Better safe than sorry" they said. ))

Comment: @gg.kaspersky I'm no specialist of finding divine messages in holy books. The fact is that in real life resources are freed. I think that short code excerpts provide concepts only and do not need to incorporate all the burden of initialization/deinitialization.

Comment: @PhilipAdler - Then whoever wrote the spec did a silly/careless thing.  Although the [man page](http://cf.ccmr.cornell.edu/cgi-bin/w3mman2html.cgi?free(3)) says that "if ptr is NULL, no operation is performed".  That's a good enough definition for me.

Comment: @PhilipAdler If you really wanna fight over `free(NULL)` being non specified (although I am pretty sure it is nowhere written like this), then you should know that even `ls` calls `free(NULL)`. After checking, the man page says that `free(ptr); free(ptr);` is undefined, and that `free(NULL)` does nothing.

@mbaitoff Then why do you bother freeing `line` then ? Still, this website is all about teaching or helping with the **best** solution possible, and freeing every allocated memory that isn't used anymore is actually the good practice to have.

Comment: @Jerksa; Can't argue with that!

Comment: For those who said that this getline is specific to GNU libc, "Both getline() and getdelim() were originally GNU extensions. They were standardized in POSIX.1-2008."

Comment: Frankly, allocating resources and leaving the responsability of deallocation to the user isn't a really smart idea in itself

Comment: To be completely honest this answer is directly from the man page. If a discussion about proper alloc/dealloc of memory is to be had, it should be posed as a separate question and surely it is already. The OP clearly only asked a question about the function at hand and its purpose - to read a file line by line. Therefore this question should have nothing to do with proper memory management or "best practices". Its irrelevant to the original question.

Comment: @PhilipAdler -- "`free(NULL)` is a non-defined operation...": from the C11 Standard, §7.22.3.3/2, ["If `ptr` is a null pointer, no action occurs."](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.3.3p2) The C89 and C99 Standards say the same thing. So, `free(NULL)` is a _defined_ non-operation.

Comment: I no longer have access to the standards I was using four years to validate where my claim comes from, so @DavidBowling may well be right.

Comment: @PhilipAdler -- the link in my comment is to the C11 Draft Standard. But you can also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6326005/6879826) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2360462/6879826). Apparently, before C89, some implementations _would_ crash on a null pointer.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder which version of the C standard younger me was reading at my university library. Might be worth a visit to my alma-mater!

Comment: Even C90 **§7.10.3.2 The `free` function** said _If `ptr` is a null pointer. no action occurs._  Only pre-standard C libraries were at liberty to mishandle `free(NULL)`.  After the C90 standard was released, some libraries probably didn't get upgraded for a few years, but by the mid-90s, it was generally safe to use `free(NULL)` — or, more plausibly, `free(ptr)` where `ptr` happened to be a null pointer.

Comment: If you know the maximum length of a line, using `fgets` is a simpler approach that also doesn't need the heap.

Comment: @Nark it was already discussed like eight years ago and ruled out, check the documentation and comments above.

Answer (score 78):

```
FILE* filePointer;
int bufferLength = 255;
char buffer[bufferLength]; /* not ISO 90 compatible */

filePointer = fopen("file.txt", "r");

while(fgets(buffer, bufferLength, filePointer)) {
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
}

fclose(filePointer);
```

Comment: For me this results in overwriting each line with the next. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54084577/printf-overwriting-strcat-appends-only-first-line-of-the-file) based on the above answer.

Comment: If you're ok with lines being limited to a certain length, this is the best answer. Otherwise using `getline` is a good alternative. I agree the `FILE *` cast is unnecessary.

Comment: It should be const int bufferLength if pedantic:)

Comment: `\n` in `printf()` is unnecessary as well, since we are already printing them line by line, and a line break already exists inside the txt file.

Comment: One of the great answer ever. Just by ```fgets``` function. `\n` is unnecessarily added because the file has already new lines.

Answer (score 24):

In your `readLine` function, you return a pointer to the `line` array (Strictly speaking, a pointer to its first character, but the difference is irrelevant here). Since it's an automatic variable (i.e., it's “on the stack”), the memory is reclaimed when the function returns. You see gibberish because `printf` has put its own stuff on the stack.

You need to return a dynamically allocated buffer from the function. You already have one, it's `lineBuffer`; all you have to do is truncate it to the desired length.

```
    lineBuffer[count] = '\0';
    realloc(lineBuffer, count + 1);
    return lineBuffer;
}
```

**ADDED** (response to follow-up question in comment): `readLine` returns a pointer to the characters that make up the line. This pointer is what you need to work with the contents of the line. It's also what you must pass to `free` when you've finished using the memory taken by these characters. Here's how you might use the `readLine` function:

```
char *line = readLine(file);
printf("LOG: read a line: %s\n", line);
if (strchr(line, 'a')) { puts("The line contains an a"); }
/* etc. */
free(line);
/* After this point, the memory allocated for the line has been reclaimed.
   You can't use the value of `line` again (though you can assign a new value
   to the `line` variable if you want). */
```

Comment: @Iron: I've added something to my answer, but I'm not sure what your difficulty is so it may be off the mark.

Comment: @Iron:  the answer is that you don't free it.  You document (in the API documentation) the fact that the returned buffer is malloc'd ansd needs to be freed by the caller.  Then people who use your readLine function will (hopefully!) write code similar to the snippet that Gilles has added to his answer.

Answer (score 17):

```
//open and get the file handle
FILE* fh;
fopen_s(&fh, filename, "r");

//check if file exists
if (fh == NULL){
    printf("file does not exists %s", filename);
    return 0;
}


//read line by line
const size_t line_size = 300;
char* line = malloc(line_size);
while (fgets(line, line_size, fh) != NULL)  {
    printf(line);
}
free(line);    // dont forget to free heap memory
```

Comment: There are some problems with this code: `fopen_s` makes the code unportable. `printf` will look for format specifiers and _not_ print percent signs and the following character(s) _as they are_. Null bytes will make all the characters in the rest of the line vanish. (Do not tell me null bytes cannot happen!)

Comment: And by the way, you do not solve the problem. The OP describes that the return value of his function disappears. I do not see you addressing this problem.

Comment: @Hartley   I know this is an older comment, but I am adding this so that someone doesn't read his comment and try to free(line) in the loop.  The memory for line is only allocated once before the loop begins, so it should only be free once after the loop ends.  If you try freeing line inside the loop, you will get unexpected results.  Depending on how free() treats the pointer.  If it just deallocates memory and leaves the pointer pointing at the old location the code may work.  If it assigns another value to the pointer then you will overwrite a different section of memory.

Comment: printf(line) is wrong! Do not do this. This opens your code to a string format vulnerability where you can freely read/write directly to memory via the stuff being printed. If I were to put %n/%p in the file and point the pointer back to an address in memory (in the string from the file) that I controlled, I could execute that code.

Answer (score 17):

A complete, [`fgets()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LEN 256

int main(void)
{
    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
      perror("Failed: ");
      return 1;
    }

    char buffer[MAX_LEN];
    while (fgets(buffer, MAX_LEN, fp))
    {
        // Remove trailing newline
        buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = 0;
        printf("%s\n", buffer);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
First line of file
Second line of file
Third (and also last) line of file
```

Remember, if you want to read from Standard Input (rather than a file as in this case), then all you have to do is pass `stdin` as the third parameter of `fgets()` method, like this:

```
while(fgets(buffer, MAX_LEN, stdin))
```

---

<sub>Appendix</sub>

[Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input)

[how to detect a file is opened or not in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14680232/how-to-detect-a-file-is-opened-or-not-in-c)

Comment: Hi, @gsamaras
I think we can directly pass `MAX_LEN` to fgets. I found this piece of description in: https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets
```
```

Comment: Hey @juancortez, I am passing `MAX_LEN - 1` at the 2nd argument of the method indeed!

Comment: There is no need for the `-1` in `MAX_LEN - 1`, fgets(buffer, n, fp) already reads up to n-1 characters reserving space for the null termination.

Comment: @マルちゃん だよ Yes you are right https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/, answer updated.

Answer (score 11):

`readLine()` returns pointer to local variable, which causes undefined behaviour.

To get around you can:

1. Create variable in caller function and pass its address to `readLine()`
2. Allocate memory for `line` using `malloc()` - in this case `line` will be persistent
3. Use global variable, although it is generally a bad practice

Answer (score 9):

Use [`fgets()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) to read a line from a file handle.

Answer (score 4):

Some things wrong with the example:

- you forgot to add \n to your printfs.  Also error messages should go to stderr i.e. `fprintf(stderr, ....`
- (not a biggy but) consider using `fgetc()` rather than `getc()`.  `getc()` is a macro, `fgetc()` is a proper function
- `getc()` returns an `int` so `ch` should be declared as an `int`.  This is important since the comparison with `EOF` will be handled correctly.  Some 8 bit character sets use `0xFF` as a valid character (ISO-LATIN-1 would be an example) and `EOF` which is -1, will be `0xFF` if assigned to a `char`.
- There is a potential buffer overflow at the line

  ```
  lineBuffer[count] = '\0';
  ```

  If the line is exactly 128 characters long, `count` is 128 at the point that gets executed.
- As others have pointed out, `line` is a locally declared array.  You can't return a pointer to it.
- `strncpy(count + 1)` will copy at most `count + 1` characters but will terminate if it hits `'\0'`  Because you set `lineBuffer[count]` to `'\0'` you know it will never get to `count + 1`.  However, if it did, it would not put a terminating `'\0'` on, so you need to do it.  You often see something like the following:

  ```
  char buffer [BUFFER_SIZE];
  strncpy(buffer, sourceString, BUFFER_SIZE - 1);
  buffer[BUFFER_SIZE - 1] = '\0';
  ```
- if you `malloc()` a line to return (in place of your local `char` array), your return type should be `char*` - drop the `const`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my several hours... Reading whole file line by line.

```
char * readline(FILE *fp, char *buffer)
{
    int ch;
    int i = 0;
    size_t buff_len = 0;

    buffer = malloc(buff_len + 1);
    if (!buffer) return NULL;  // Out of memory

    while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != '\n' && ch != EOF)
    {
        buff_len++;
        void *tmp = realloc(buffer, buff_len + 1);
        if (tmp == NULL)
        {
            free(buffer);
            return NULL; // Out of memory
        }
        buffer = tmp;

        buffer[i] = (char) ch;
        i++;
    }
    buffer[i] = '\0';

    // Detect end
    if (ch == EOF && (i == 0 || ferror(fp)))
    {
        free(buffer);
        return NULL;
    }
    return buffer;
}

void lineByline(FILE * file){
char *s;
while ((s = readline(file, 0)) != NULL)
{
    puts(s);
    free(s);
    printf("\n");
}
}

int main()
{
    char *fileName = "input-1.txt";
    FILE* file = fopen(fileName, "r");
    lineByline(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `fgetc` instead of `fgets`?

Comment: It would be better if it didnt realloc for every character, like if it used a global buffer and doubled the size every time a character would go over the size of the buffer.

Answer (score 2):

```
const char *readLine(FILE *file, char* line) {

    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Error: file pointer is null.");
        exit(1);
    }

    int maximumLineLength = 128;
    char *lineBuffer = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * maximumLineLength);

    if (lineBuffer == NULL) {
        printf("Error allocating memory for line buffer.");
        exit(1);
    }

    char ch = getc(file);
    int count = 0;

    while ((ch != '\n') && (ch != EOF)) {
        if (count == maximumLineLength) {
            maximumLineLength += 128;
            lineBuffer = realloc(lineBuffer, maximumLineLength);
            if (lineBuffer == NULL) {
                printf("Error reallocating space for line buffer.");
                exit(1);
            }
        }
        lineBuffer[count] = ch;
        count++;

        ch = getc(file);
    }

    lineBuffer[count] = '\0';
    char line[count + 1];
    strncpy(line, lineBuffer, (count + 1));
    free(lineBuffer);
    return line;

}


char linebuffer[256];
while (!feof(myFile)) {
    const char *line = readLine(myFile, linebuffer);
    printf("%s\n", line);
}
```

note that the 'line' variable is declared in calling function and then passed, so your `readLine` function fills predefined buffer and just returns it. This is the way most of C libraries work.

There are other ways, which I'm aware of:

- defining the `char line[]` as static
  (`static char line[MAX_LINE_LENGTH]`
  -> it will hold it's value AFTER returning from the function). -> bad,
  the function is not reentrant, and
  race condition can occur -> if you
  call it twice from two threads, it
  will overwrite it's results
- `malloc()`ing the char line[], and
  freeing it in calling functions ->
  too many expensive `malloc`s, and,
  delegating the responsibility to free the buffer to another function (the most elegant solution is to call `malloc` and `free` on any buffers in same function)

btw, 'explicit' casting  from `char*` to `const char*` is redundant.

btw2, there is no need to `malloc()` the lineBuffer, just define it `char lineBuffer[128]`, so you don't need to free it

btw3 do not use 'dynamic sized stack arrays' (defining the array as `char arrayName[some_nonconstant_variable]`), if you don't exactly know what are you doing, it works only in C99.

Comment: *note that the 'line' variable is declared in calling function and then passed,* - you probably should have deleted the local declaration of line in the function then.  Also, you need to tell the function how long the buffer is that you are passing and think of a strategy for handling lines that are too long for the buffer you pass in.

Answer (score 2):

```
void readLine(FILE* file, char* line, int limit)
{
    int i;
    int read;

    read = fread(line, sizeof(char), limit, file);
    line[read] = '\0';

    for(i = 0; i <= read;i++)
    {
        if('\0' == line[i] || '\n' == line[i] || '\r' == line[i])
        {
            line[i] = '\0';
            break;
        }
    }

    if(i != read)
    {
        fseek(file, i - read + 1, SEEK_CUR);
    }
}
```

what about this one?

Answer (score 2):

Implement method to read, and get content from a file (input1.txt)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void testGetFile() {
    // open file
    FILE *fp = fopen("input1.txt", "r");
    size_t len = 255;
    // need malloc memory for line, if not, segmentation fault error will occurred.
    char *line = malloc(sizeof(char) * len);
    // check if file exist (and you can open it) or not
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("can open file input1.txt!");
        return;
    }
    while(fgets(line, len, fp) != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", line);
    }
    free(line);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the ANSI functions for reading a line, eg. fgets. After calling you need free() in calling context, eg:

```
...
const char *entirecontent=readLine(myFile);
puts(entirecontent);
free(entirecontent);
...

const char *readLine(FILE *file)
{
  char *lineBuffer=calloc(1,1), line[128];

  if ( !file || !lineBuffer )
  {
    fprintf(stderr,"an ErrorNo 1: ...");
    exit(1);
  }

  for(; fgets(line,sizeof line,file) ; strcat(lineBuffer,line) )
  {
    if( strchr(line,'\n') ) *strchr(line,'\n')=0;
    lineBuffer=realloc(lineBuffer,strlen(lineBuffer)+strlen(line)+1);
    if( !lineBuffer )
    {
      fprintf(stderr,"an ErrorNo 2: ...");
      exit(2);
    }
  }
  return lineBuffer;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My implement from scratch:

```
FILE *pFile = fopen(your_file_path, "r");
int nbytes = 1024;
char *line = (char *) malloc(nbytes);
char *buf = (char *) malloc(nbytes);

size_t bytes_read;
int linesize = 0;
while (fgets(buf, nbytes, pFile) != NULL) {
    bytes_read = strlen(buf);
    // if line length larger than size of line buffer
    if (linesize + bytes_read > nbytes) {
        char *tmp = line;
        nbytes += nbytes / 2;
        line = (char *) malloc(nbytes);
        memcpy(line, tmp, linesize);
        free(tmp);
    }
    memcpy(line + linesize, buf, bytes_read);
    linesize += bytes_read;

    if (feof(pFile) || buf[bytes_read-1] == '\n') {
        handle_line(line);
        linesize = 0;
        memset(line, '\0', nbytes);
    }
}

free(buf);
free(line);
```

Comment: Why are you using the heap (malloc) instead of the stack? It seems there's a simpler stack based solution with `fgets` that could be used.

Answer (score 1):

Provide a portable and generic `getdelim` function, test passed via msvc, clang, gcc.

```
/*
 * An implementation conform IEEE Std 1003.1-2017:
 * https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getdelim.html
 *
 * <nio.h>:
 * https://github.com/junjiemars/c/blob/c425bd0e49df35a2649327664d3f6cd610791996/src/posix/nio.h
 * <nio.c>:
 * https://github.com/junjiemars/c/blob/c425bd0e49df35a2649327664d3f6cd610791996/src/posix/nio.c
 *
*/

#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>


/*
 * LINE_MAX dependents on OS' implementations so check it first.
 * https://github.com/junjiemars/c/blob/c425bd0e49df35a2649327664d3f6cd610791996/src/posix/nlim_auto_check
 */
#define NM_LINE_MAX  4096       /* Linux */

#if (MSVC)
typedef SSIZE_T  ssize_t;
#  if !defined(SSIZE_MAX)
#    define SSIZE_MAX  ((ssize_t)((size_t)((ssize_t)-1) >> 1))
#  endif
#endif


ssize_t getdelim(char **restrict lineptr, size_t *restrict n, int delimiter,
                 FILE *restrict stream);

#if defined(getline)
#  undef getline
#endif
#define getline(lp, n, f)  getdelim((lp), (n), 0x0a, (f))


ssize_t
getdelim(char **restrict lineptr, size_t *restrict n, int delimiter,
         FILE *restrict stream)
{
    int       c;
    char     *p, *p1;
    ssize_t   len;

  if (NULL == lineptr || NULL == n || NULL == stream
      || (UCHAR_MAX < delimiter || delimiter < 0))
    {
      errno = EINVAL;
      return EOF;
    }

  if (feof(stream) || ferror(stream))
    {
      return EOF;
    }

    if (0 == *lineptr)
    {
      if (0 == *n)
        {
          *n = NM_LINE_MAX;
        }

      *lineptr = malloc(*n);
      if (0 == *lineptr)
        {
          return EOF;
        }
    }

  p = *lineptr;
  len = 0;

    while (EOF != (c = fgetc(stream)))
    {
      if (SSIZE_MAX == (ssize_t) len)
        {
          errno = EOVERFLOW;
          return EOF;
        }

      if ((size_t) len == (*n - 1))
        {
          *n <<= 1;
          p1 = realloc(*lineptr, *n);
          if (0 == p1)
            {
              return EOF;
            }
          *lineptr = p1;
          p = p1 + len;
        }
      *p++ = (char) c;
      len++;

      if (c == delimiter)
        {
          break;
        }
    }

  if (ferror(stream))
    {
      return EOF;
    }

  *p = 0;
    return len;
}



int
main(void)
{
  FILE     *fp;
  char     *line  =  NULL;
  size_t    len   =  0;
  ssize_t   read;

  fp = fopen("/some-file", "r");
  if (fp == NULL)
    exit(1);
  while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
    printf("Retrieved line of length %zu :\n", read);
    printf("%s", line);
  }
  if (ferror(fp)) {
    /* handle error */
  }
  free(line);
  fclose(fp);

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: Why do this when `fgets` exists?

Comment: does fgets can customize line delimiters or customize what to do about current lines?

Comment: `getdelim` allows for customized delimiters. Also I do notice don't have a line length limit -- in this case you can use the stack with `getline`. (Both described here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html)

Comment: do you talk about just Linux , the question is about how to read line in C, right?

Comment: This works for any standard c implementation (`getdelim` and `getline` were standardized in POSIX.1-2008, someone else mentions on this page). `fgets` is also standard c, and not linux specific

Comment: POSIX C != C standard, why you talking about POSIX? POSIX is another topic.

Comment: True, but `getline`, `fgets`, and `getdelim` I believe work on Mac, Linux, and Windows.

Comment: There are no getdelim on Windows.

Comment: Ah, you're right. This discussion helps me understand when your code would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You make the mistake of returning a pointer to an automatic variable.
The variable line is allocated in the stack and only lives as long as the function lives.
You are not allowed to return a pointer to it, because as soon as it returns the memory will be given elsewhere.

```
const char* func x(){
    char line[100];
    return (const char*) line; //illegal
}
```

To avoid this, you either return a pointer to memory which resides on the heap eg. lineBuffer
and it should be the user's responsibility to call free() when he is done with it.
Alternatively you can ask the user to pass you as an argument a memory address on which to write the line contents at.

Comment: There is a difference between illegal and undefine behavior ^^.

Answer (score 0):

I want a code from ground 0 so i did this to  read the content of dictionary's word line by line.

char temp_str[20];  // you can change the buffer size according to your requirements And A single line's length in a File.

**Note** I've initialized the buffer With Null character each time I read line.This function can be Automated  But Since I need A proof of Concept and want to design a programme Byte By Byte

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
int i;
char temp_ch;
FILE *fp=fopen("data.txt","r");
while(temp_ch!=EOF)
{
 i=0;
  char temp_str[20]={'\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0'};
while(temp_ch!='\n')
{
  temp_ch=fgetc(fp);
  temp_str[i]=temp_ch;
  i++;
}
if(temp_ch=='\n')
{
temp_ch=fgetc(fp);
temp_str[i]=temp_ch;
}
printf("%s",temp_str);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: your program would work if your brackets were in the right places ;) e.g. `int main() {`

Comment: Incidentally, you don't need to specify all 20 '\0'.   You can just write:  `code` char temp_str[20] = {'\0'}; `code`  c will automatically fill each slot with a null terminator since the way array declarations work is that if an array is initialized with less elements that the array contains, the last element will be fill out the remaining elements.

Comment: I believe `char temp_str[20] = {0}` also fills up the entire character array with null terminators.