# Creating files in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a program that automatically creates a file and writes a message in it. My first attempt was from using an example by w3 schools:

```
FILE *fptr;

// Open a file in read mode
fptr = fopen("filename.txt", "r");

// Store the content of the file
char myString[100];

// Read the content and store it inside myString
fgets(myString, 100, fptr);

// Print the file content
printf("%s", myString);

// Close the file
fclose(fptr);
```

It worked. Then as soon as I added different text, it was no longer making the file. I'm running the code through the macOS terminal:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  FILE *fptr;

  // Open a file in writing mode
  fptr = fopen("emile1.txt", "w");

  // Write some text to the file
  fprintf(fptr, " _____                                                         _____ \n( ___ )-------------------------------------------------------( ___ )\n |   |                                                         |   | \n |   |  █████   █████                                          |   | \n |   | ░░███   ░░███                                           |   |\n |   |  ░███    ░███   ██████   ████████  ████████  █████ ████ |   | \n|   |  ░███████████  ░░░░░███ ░░███░░███░░███░░███░░███ ░███  |   | \n |   |  ░███░░░░░███   ███████  ░███ ░███ ░███ ░███ ░███ ░███  |   | \n |   |  ░███    ░███  ███░░███  ░███ ░███ ░███ ░███ ░███ ░███  |   | \n |   |  █████   █████░░████████ ░███████  ░███████  ░░███████  |   | \n |   | ░░░░░   ░░░░░  ░░░░░░░░  ░███░░░   ░███░░░    ░░░░░███  |   | \n |   |                          ░███      ░███       ███ ░███  |   | \n |   |                          █████     █████     ░░██████   |   | \n |   |                         ░░░░░     ░░░░░       ░░░░░░    |   | ");

  // Close the file
  fclose(fptr);

  return 0;
}
```

Does anyone know what's wrong?

I'm not sure why it stopped creating the file. Will it appear in the same directory everytime?

---

[image: test]

I don't think i got any errors back. Would they appear here?

Comment: Are you getting errors? What is the current behavior?

Comment: It looks like you are both writing to and reading from a file, perhaps you should clarify this in the question / title.  Also, have you looked at the file in an ordinary editor?

Comment: Permissions problem that prevented you from creating the `emile1.txt` file in the current working directory in the terminal?

Comment: ***Will it appear in the same directory everytime?*** It will place it in the current working directory which may or not be the same location as the executable. In the terminal it should be in whatever folder you are currently in.

Comment: "Would they appear here?" Two types of errors: compiler and runtime. You showed what you execute when you compile and link to produce an executable called `runme`. But you don't show what happens when you execute it: `% ls -l; ./runme; ls -l`

Comment: [mre] – unless a simpler example doesn’t produce the same problem (which would also be valuable information to include), simplify to `fprintf(fptr, "hello")`. And yes, you to [check for errors explicitly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14680232/how-to-detect-a-file-is-opened-or-not-in-c) in C, on everything (`fopen`, `fprintf`, and `fclose`).

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your code is that it's not checking whether the file is successfully opened or not. In the first code snippet, you opened the file in read mode, and it worked. However, in the second code snippet, you opened the file in write mode, and if there was an issue opening the file, it would not be created, and `fptr` would be `NULL`.

You should check if the file is **successfully opened** before writing to it. If the file cannot be opened, you should **handle the error**.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  FILE *fptr;

  // Open a file in writing mode
  fptr = fopen("emile1.txt", "w");

  // Check if the file is successfully opened
  if (fptr == NULL) {
    printf("Error opening the file.\n");
    return 1;  // Return an error code
  }

  // Write some text to the file
  fprintf(fptr, " _____\n...  ... \n");

  // Close the file
  fclose(fptr);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A re-write, with some error checking to test OP's code follows **may** illuminate OP's troubles.

---

The *shifted* line near the middle appears to be OP's mis-coding.

Using `fprintf(fptr, " _____  ...");` is a poor choice as the long line, *as a format*, may conceal a `'%'` in the encoding of non-ASCII characters.

Better as:

```
fprintf(fptr, "%s", " _____  ..."); // or
fputs(" _____  ...", fptr);
```

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  FILE *fptr;

  // Open a file in writing mode
  fptr = fopen("emile1.txt", "w");
  if (fptr == NULL) {
    puts("Unable to open file");
  } else {
    // Write some text to the file
    fputs( //
        " _____                                                         _____ \n"
        "( ___ )-------------------------------------------------------( ___ )\n"
        " |   |                                                         |   | \n"
        " |   |  █████   █████                                          |   | \n"
        " |   | ░░███   ░░███                                           |   |\n"
        " |   |  ░███    ░███   ██████   ████████  ████████  █████ ████ |   | \n"
        "|   |  ░███████████  ░░░░░███ ░░███░░███░░███░░███░░███ ░███  |   | \n"
        " |   |  ░███░░░░░███   ███████  ░███ ░███ ░███ ░███ ░███ ░███  |   | \n"
        " |   |  ░███    ░███  ███░░███  ░███ ░███ ░███ ░███ ░███ ░███  |   | \n"
        " |   |  █████   █████░░████████ ░███████  ░███████  ░░███████  |   | \n"
        " |   | ░░░░░   ░░░░░  ░░░░░░░░  ░███░░░   ░███░░░    ░░░░░███  |   | \n"
        " |   |                          ░███      ░███       ███ ░███  |   | \n"
        " |   |                          █████     █████     ░░██████   |   | \n"
        " |   |                         ░░░░░     ░░░░░       ░░░░░░    |   | ", fptr);

    // Close the file
    fclose(fptr);
    fptr = fopen("emile1.txt", "r");
    int ch;
    while ((ch = fgetc(fptr)) != EOF) {
      putchar(ch);
    }
    fclose(fptr);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

My output was as expected.