# How to use arbitrary number of scanf() format specifiers?

Tags: c, loops, scanf

I want to use infinite type specifiers (`%d`) in `scanf()` function.

For example-

```
printf("Enter numbers: \t");
scanf("--%d SPECIFIERS--");
```

So its not definite how many nos. the user will enter.  I don't want my program to ask the user the 'numbers of characters'.. but I want to allow any the numbers of characters. But its not possible to enter infinite `%d` in `scanf()`.

So can anyone please tell what is the C program of finding average of numbers given by the user (if you dont know how much nos. the user will give and you don't want the program to ask 'how many numbers.')?

Comment: Loop. Allocate memory dynamically. Average. Profit?

Comment: Or better yet, if you care only about the average, then update it every iteration. *Think* about how the average of a,b and c relates to the average of a and b.

Comment: I want to allow users to enter as many nos. they want. But I dont know how many nos. the user will enter, so how can I make scanf() type specifiers to accept any no. of numbers?

Comment: @StoryTeller: Votes are anonymous; what's the point of asking?

Comment: @KeithThompson, to learn what merit that person saw in this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is tricky.  2 approaches

1 - `fgets()`  Read 1 line, then parse

```
char buffer[1000];
int count = 0;
double sum = 0;
int num;
fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin);
const char *p = buffer;
int n;
while (sscanf(p, "%d%n", &num, &n) == 1) {
  p += n;
  ; // do something with `num`
  sum += num;
  count++;
}     
printf("Average %f\n", sum/count);
```

2 - Lets say you infinite input ends with the end-of-line.  Now the problem is that `%d` will consume all leading whitespace, including `\n`.  Thus we need to consume and test all whitespace beforehand

```
int count = 0;
double sum = 0;
int num;
for (;;) {
  int ws = 0;
  while (isspace(ws = fgetc(stdin)) && (ws != '\n'));
  if (ws == '\n') break;
  ungetc(ws, stdin);
  if (scanf("%d", &num) != 1) break;
  ; // do something with num
  sum += num;
  count++;
}
printf("Average %f\n", sum/count);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really interested in infinite number of inputs the just try this

```
while(1)
{
    printf("Enter numbers: \t");
    scanf("%d", number);
}
```

It will take input until you forcibly close your program!
But does it make any sense of doing this ?

Comment: I dont want program to ask user to press anything to finish. please see my question again.

Answer (score 0):

If the user input is always numbers separeted by spaces and then at the end is an enter (newline). Then you can use the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int input;
    char c;
    while (scanf(" %d%c", &input, &c) == 2 ) {
        printf("number is %d\n", input);
        if ( c == '\n') break;
    }
}
```

---

If the use want to communicate the number of input as argument

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int number_of_input = atoi(argv[1]);
    int input, i;
    for (i=0; i<number_of_input; i++) {
        scanf(" %d", &input);
    }
}
```

and when you call you program. you call it in this way:

```
$ myprogram 5
```

and 5 here is the number of the integer that you can input

- `myprogram` will be saved in `argv[0]`
- `5` will be saved in `argv[1]`

`myprogram` and `5` are saved as sting in the `argv[]` array. `atoi(argv[1])` will convert the `"5"` as string to `5` as integer

---

you can make the user enter an infinite integer input in this way too:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int input, i;
    while (1) {
        scanf(" %d", &input);
    }
}
```

And you can give the user a way to stop this infinite loop:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int input;
    while (scanf(" %d", &input) != EOF) {
        //....
    }
}
```

here you can stop the infinite loop with

EOF = <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> (for Linux)

EOF = <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> (for Windows)

Comment: see my question. i dnt want program to ask users how many nos. will he enter.

 I want to allow users to enter
as many nos. they want. But I
dont know how many nos. the
user will enter, so how can I
make scanf() type specifiers
to accept any no. of numbers?

Comment: you can make an infinite loop while

Comment: IF I want this?? ENTER
NUMBERS SEPARATED BY
WHITESPACES: 56 989 859
582 6949 //These 5 numbers
are given by user and the user
then pressed enter, And I dont
know how many %d to enter in
scanf as it depends on user
that how many nos. would he
enter AVERAGE: ***** //*****
should be replaced by the
average answer. –

Comment: @user2583127 ok I see now. so the user input is always numbers separeted by spaces and then at the end is an enter (newline). Is this correct?

Comment: @user2583127 I update my answer I added the way of  the user input is always numbers separeted by spaces and then at the end is an enter (newline)

Comment: @mohamed, I would suggest a better format string. First of all, the space before `%d` is unnecessary. `%d` already consumes whitespaces. Second, after the last digit there could be extra whitespaces (you can't prevent user from doing that). So, it's better to ignore all non-digit-non-enter characters before reading that character): `scanf("%d%*[^-+1234567890\n]%c", &input, &c)` and immediately after `ungetc(c, stdin);` to put back the test character (it could belong to the next digit, since we ignored whitespace).

Answer (score 0):

At first reading, the solution to a problem like this is to loop until the user inputs a "done" character. This could be a letter `Q` for example. By reading in the input as a string you can process both numbers and letters. The code below processes one input at a time (followed by ) - with the possibility to either Quit (terminate program), or Clear (restart calculation, keep program running):

```
printf("Enter numbers to average. Type Q to quit, or C to clear calculation.\n");
char buf[256];
double sum=0, temp;
int ii = 0;
while(1)
{
    printf("Input: \t");
    fgets(buf, 255, stdin);
    if (tolower(buf[0])=='q') break;
    // allow user to "clear" input and start again:
    if (tolower(buf[0])=='c') {
      sum = 0;
      ii = 0;
      printf("Calculation cleared; ready for new input\n");
      continue;
    }
    ii++;
    sscanf(buf, "%lf", &temp);
    sum += temp;
    printf("At this point the average is %lf\n", sum / (double)ii);
}

printf("Done. The final average of the %d numbers is %lf\n", ii, sum / ii);
```

**EDIT** Following some back-and-forth in the comments to this and other answers, here is a solution that addresses your problem. Code has been tested - it compiles, runs, gives expected results:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
  double sum=0;
  int ii=0;
  char buf[256], *temp;
  char *token;

  printf("Enter the numbers to average on a single line, separated by space, then press <ENTER>\n");
  fgets(buf, 255, stdin);
  temp = buf;
  while((token=strtok(temp, " ")) != NULL) {
    temp = NULL; // after the first call to strtok, want to call it with first argument = NULL
    sum += atof(token);
    ii++;
    printf("Next token read is number %d: '%s'\n", ii, token); // so you see what is going on
                                                               // remove in final code!!
  }
  printf("AVERAGE: ***** %lf *****\n", sum / (double)ii);
  return 0;
}
```

**One more edit** If you want to use `getline` instead (which you asked about in the comments - and it's even safer than `fgets` since it will increase the buffer size as needed), you would change to change the code a little bit. I am just giving some of the pertinent lines - you can figure out the rest, I'm sure:

```
double sum=0;
char *buf, *temp;      // declaring buf as a pointer, not an array
int nBytes = 256;      // need size in a variable so we can pass pointer to getline()
buf = malloc(nBytes);  // "suggested" size of buffer

printf("Enter numbers to average on a single line, separated with spaces\n")

if (getline(&buf, &nBytes, stdin) > 0) {
 temp = buf;
 // rest of code as before
}
else {
 // error reading from input: warn user
}
```

I am sure you can figure it out from here...

Comment: Note - I saw your comment about "not wanting to do anything to end input" after writing my answer so I updated it a little bit. You get the average after each number entered. But at some point the program needs to know when to stop - either before it is run, or at the end. I think the latter is better.

Comment: Answer updated. User does not have to type q to quit - it will report average of all numbers entered, but it just never ends... Is that better?

Comment: IF I want this??

ENTER NUMBERS SEPARATED BY WHITESPACES: 56 989 859 582 6949 //These 5 numbers are given by user and the user then pressed enter, And I dont know how many %d to enter in scanf as it depends on user that how many nos. would he enter
AVERAGE: ***** //***** should be replaced by the average answer.

Comment: Ah that is clearer. You don't like the letter Q but you like the "enter" key. It is just a different ASCII character. But I have now updated my answer.

Comment: I will try it just now & update! By the way we should not use     gets() . so is using     fgets() a good idea?

and can gets be replaced by getline????

Comment: UPDATE
Edited program gives this error: Line 9: stdin undeclared

So I tried adding stdio.h header file then it gives this error: Line 11: lvalue expected

Comment: Apologies - I should have tested my code before posting. Updated, working now (I believe).

Comment: As for your `gets` vs `fgets` question: `fgets` contains the "no more than n characters" parameter, while `gets` will allow buffer overflow. Big difference. `getline` can work too, and is safer since it will resize the block of data in which the result is stored. I will update my answer...

Answer (score 0):

You should have *some* way of knowing where the input ends. There are many ways for it and each has a possibly different solution. The two most common ones would be:

#### Input finishes at end-of-line

The solution is to [read one line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3501681/912144) and then parse the line to get your numbers until the line ends.

This has the benefit that the program could ask for other input afterwards for other parts of the program. The disadvantage is that the user has to input all the numbers in the same line.

#### Input finishes at end-of-file

Simply loop, reading one number until end of file:

```
while (scanf("%d", &num) == 1)
    /* do something with num */
```

Note: the user can enter end-of-file in a Linux console with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

Comment: **!!!Don't ever use `gets`!!!**. It's inherently unsafe and is deprecated. Yes it can be done with `getline`.

Comment: Note - typing an "end of file" character (or a carriage return) is really not that different from typing any other character (say, the letter `Q`). What is the real requirement here...?

Comment: @Shahbaz: `getline` is not a C standard function.

Comment: @KeithThompson, I know. I didn't want to get into the details of how to read a line since that would be a different (and already answered) question.

Comment: @Floris, the difference is that typing end of file makes `scanf` fail, which is different from basically all other characters. Even though in this particular case any nondigit (except `-` and `+`) would make this `scanf` fail.

Comment: @Shahbaz - I was referencing the "what is the real requirement here" question, not the "why does A work and B doesn't". Sorry if I caused confusion.