# How to read a line from a file in C

Tags: c, file, getline

I want to read lines from a file line-by-line, but it's not working for me.

Here is what I tried to do:

```
FILE *file;
char *line = NULL;
int len = 0;
char read;
file=fopen(argv[1], "r");

if (file == NULL)
    return 1;

while ((read = getline(&line, len, file)) != -1) {
    printf("Retrieved line of length %s :\n", &read);
    printf("%s", line);
}

if (line)
    free(line);

return 0;
```

Any suggestions why that isn't working?

Comment: 2 mistakes ... 1:- line is just a pointer, that pointer needs to point to some malloced memory .... 2:- len = 0, why do want to read 0 bytes???? .. google for a "simple file operation program in c" ...

Comment: @Deepthought No, that's not how `getline()` works. It allocates memory for the line itself.

Comment: Straight example at [man getline](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getline).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C read file line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501338/c-read-file-line-by-line)

Comment: Your compiler should have told you that the second argument to `getline` is wrong. It expects a pointer and not an integer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get it to work correctly, there's a few changes.

Change `int len` to `size_t len` for the correct type.

`getline()` syntax is incorrect. It should be:

```
while ((read = getline(&line, &len, file)) != -1) {
```

And the `printf` line should also be modified, to print the number returned instead of a `char` and string interpretation:

```
printf("Retrieved line of length %d:\n", read);
```

Comment: Note `read` should be type `ssize_t` and not `char`.  2 problems:`char` may be `unsigned char` and never == -1 and `char` is not the same range as `ssize_t`.  The `printf()` format specifier is a bit of a problem too.  Suggest: `printf("Retrieved line of length %lld:\n", (long long) read);`

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively you  can also use this code. It will read the whole file line by line and print those lines.

```
char buf[1000];

ptr_file =fopen("input3.txt","r");
if (!ptr_file)
    return 1;

while (fgets(buf,1000, ptr_file)!=NULL)
    printf("%s",buf);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your second argument to `getline()` is (very) wrong.

It should be `size_t *`, you're passing `int`. You should have received compiler warnings for this problem.

Make it:

```
size_t len;
```

and in the call:

```
getline(&line, &len, file)
```

Also the return value is of type `ssize_t`, not `char`.

You should really read [the manual page for `getline()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getline) and make sure you understand it, before writing code to use the function.