# Reading a file from a specified line to another

Tags: c

I currently have a shell script in C that takes a command of a file, two numbers, mth line and nth line, and supposedly should output whats in between those lines:

for example:

```
./output file1 2 6
```

would output file from line 2 to line 6

I have it implemented currently in a way of outputting the whole file, I have been trying to change it to output specifically between those lines

this is my code

```
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int file;
    int size;
    int l[1000];

    int firstNum = atoi(argv[2]);

    int secondNum = atoi(argv[3]);


    file = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);

    if( file == -1)
    {
        printf("\n cannot open file \n");
    }

    while ((size=read(file,l,80)) > 0)
        write(1,l,size);




}
```

I tried to change `l` and `size` to `firstNum` and `secondNum`, which are the numbers entered from the command line, but still did not work and outputted one single line.

What is a better way of doing so ?

Comment: "a shell script in C"?

Comment: Much the simplest is `char cmd[256]; snprintf(cmd, sizeof(cmd), "sed -n '%s,%sp %s", argv[2], argv[3], argv[1]); system(cmd);`.  Run `sed` to print only between the two line numbers passed as arguments on the file specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues with your code, so just go through them sequentially:

- It's better to use high level `fopen` rather than low level `open` to open a file. So it's better to write this way:

  ```
  FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  if (file == NULL)
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  ```
- Your `read` is wrong as it reads exactly 80 characters instead of a line as you expect.

  ```
  while ((size=read(file,l,80)) > 0)   // <-- WRONG because this reads 80 chars instead of one line
  ```
- For similar reason as with `open`, it's better to use alternative like `printf` instead of low level `read` and `write`.
- To read line by line, you should use library function `getline`.
- To control what line number to print, a simple way is to have a variable tracking what line number and compare with your command line arguments.

So put them together, you would need something like this:

```
FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
if (file == NULL)
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

int line_num = 0;

char * line = NULL;
size_t len = 0;
ssize_t read = 0;
while ((read = getline(&line, &len, file)) != -1)
{
    line_num++;
    if( firstNum <= line_num && line_num <= secondNum )
    {
        printf( "line %d: %s", line_num, line );
        if( line_num == secondNum )
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: you should break out of the loop when you reach `secondNum`

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at this post: [C read file line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501338/c-read-file-line-by-line)

From there it should be a simple matter of counting lines read and discarding them until you have read `firstNum` lines at which point print until you've reached `secondNum`.