# reading a file in c line by line

Tags: c, string, file, lines

So guys I have a file with various lines such as "GAME: 1 Bob (@) - 404" the name of the player is Bob and his highest score is 404 and there are many lines like this. Basically I have to read each line and see who has the highest score and print his name and score out in c. So far I have this:

```
  FILE *fp;
  char * line = NULL;
  size_t len = 0;
  size_t read;

  fp - fopen("Leaderboard.dat", "r");
  if (fp == NULL) {
  printf("File empty/unable to open");
  }
```

now im actually not sure how to do this properly..

Comment: This code has undefined behavior. `fp - fopen( ... );` is wrong. Also, what have you tried?. Reading a file line by line is a very common task, just google it. You will find a million examples.

Comment: i cant seem to figure it out, like  i can fetch the line but i cant seem to compare which line contains the highest score and print that line out

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C read file line by line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501338/c-read-file-line-by-line). And what exactly do you think subtracting `fopen()` from an uninitialized `FILE *fp` is going to do?

Comment: So your real question is, "*how to find a substring in a text line?*", is it?

Comment: This is not an [mcve]. What error message are you getting? What did you learn when running it under debugger? Could you at least try and add lines that read the file and possibly store the name and score of the highest scorer as you read each line? it's just an `if score < whateverwasread score=whateverwasread;` inside a loop `while (fgets(line, maxline, fp) != NULL)`.

Comment: @iharob - I think the real question is: Can you help me write a code cause I have no idea where to start.

Comment: @jasspreet - if you can't figure out how to parse a line, or read a line, then maybe your instructor wasn't teaching the language effectively. Time to find a new instructor.

Comment: I searched, and there is not a single question mark in your "question".

Answer (score 0):

```
char buffer[100];
char code[4];
char name[100];
int maxScore=0;
char maxName[100];
char maxCode[4];

while(fscanf(fp,"%s %s %s %c %d",buffer,name,code,buffer[0],&score) !=EOF)
{
    if(score>maxScore)
    {
        maxScore=score;
        strcpy(maxCode,code);
        strcpy(maxName,name);
    }
}
printf("Name: %s. Code %s Score %d",maxName,maxCode,maxScore);
```

Comment: It would be better to check that `fscanf` returned the number of elements requested (in this case 5), since `fscanf` may return a number fewer than that (for example, if not the `%d` fails to match an integer etc). Also, `buffer[0]` is of type `char` but `%c` expects `char *`. Lastly, the `%s` specifiers are unbounded, so there is the potential for buffer overflow.

Answer (score -1):

This code should do the trick,
Just note it has not been checked or compiled.

```
   FILE *fp;

   fp = fopen("Leaderboard.dat", "r");

   if (fp == NULL) {
       printf("File empty/unable to open");
   }

    char buffer[100];
    char name[100];
    char winnerName[100];
    char code;
   char winnerCode;
    int maxScore = 0;

    while(fgets(buffer,1000,fp)!=NULL)
    {
        // getting the points from the end of the line
        int last = strlen(buffer) -1;
        while(isdigit(buffer[last]))
        {
            last--;
        }
        int score = atoi(buffer+last+1);

       //getting the name from the start of the line
        int i = 0;
        while(!isdigit(buffer[i]))
        {
            i++;
        }
        i ++;
        int k=0;
        while(!isdigit(buffer[i]))
       {
           if(isalpha(buffer[i]))
           {
                name[k++] = buffer[i];
            }
           if(buffer[i] == '(' )
           {
               code= buffer[i+1];
           }
           i++;
        }
        name[k] = '\0';
        // is greater then max
        if(score > maxScore)
        {
             strcpy(winnerName,name);
             maxScore = score;            
             winnerCode=code;
        }
    }

   printf("Name: %s , Code: %c, Score: %d",winnerName,winnerCode,maxScore);
```

Comment: Pretty sure this will not compile. :/

Comment: Why do you think..?

Comment: wanna bet? it came straight from my nexus phone!

Comment: im getting fgets: too few arguments for call (error on the while (fgets(fp, buffer) != NULL) line

Comment: Haha, no Dr., it's cool now, that you edited! However, when I run it I will get `: `..

Comment: i fixed it copy again

Comment: @gsamaras what...?

Comment: it works except that the name winnerName is printing "GAME" but not the name

Comment: I tried with the file I have in my answer but it didn't printed the score, but if @jasspreet says it's ok, then I pass.. :)

Comment: @jass preet now it is fixed

Comment: i belie its printing garbage for the name but the scores are perfect

Comment: by garbage you mean "(, @ ,) -" ?

Comment: @jasspreet - you belie? or perhaps you mean you believe? Either way, a quick test should confirm or deny what you believe.

Comment: if so it is easy to change

Comment: oh shit i forgot to mention the line is as following in the filw -> GAME: 1 Bob (@) - 400 and the @ is a name code so the code shud fetch the person with the highest score and print the Name the Name Code and its Score

Comment: @jasspreet try now

Comment: displays nothing now

Comment: yeah forgot " in the printf function @jaaspreet

Comment: no i fixed that and i fixed the parentheses but it actually displays nothing

Comment: Try now @jasspreet