# Reading a file, modifiying each line, storing it into a buffer, printing all at once

Tags: c, file-io

This is the file:

```
 line 1
 line 2
 line 3
```

How to read the file line by line...

Append a suffix to each line..

```
FILE *fp = fopen ("file", "r");
while (fgets (buffer, sizeof (buffer), fp) != NULL) {

    // append "test" to each line.
    // store the result in a buffer named "result"

}
fclose (fp);
```

print the result all at once:

```
printf( "%s", result );
```

Expected result :

```
 line 1test
 line 2test
 line 3test
```

Comment: You can use `getline()` function, but it is GNU specific.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please be aware that this is not a free homework delivery service. Read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then you will see that you should provide what you have tried so far and what your **specific** problem is.

Comment: You need to *concatenate* each line into your `result` buffer. There's a nice standard C function to concatenate strings (if you use your favorite search engine you should find out about it pretty quickly, as would [reading a couple of good beginners books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)).

Comment: @GauravPathak: Are you referring to the POSIX standard [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html)
function?  It is not GNU-specific, though it is not a part of standard C, either.

Comment: [sample code](http://ideone.com/nDCb9U)

Comment: So, what's the problem you're facing?  Your outline is OK — you just need to fill in the details.  You may need to use `realloc()` (and `malloc()` and `free()`) to manage the result.  Are you sure your file will be as tiny as shown?  If so, there are arguably other ways to do it.  Processing one line at a time would be more sensible than accumulating it all before writing.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501338/c-read-file-line-by-line#comment3659371_3501681) comment. That's why I thought it's GNU specific.

Comment: @GauravPathak: Ah — see this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501338/c-read-file-line-by-line#comment47696012_3501681) saying that the one you quoted is inaccurate.  (Also note that the question is from 2010, which was a long time ago when the function was still newly added to POSIX.  It is fairly widely available now; it was probably less so back then.)

Answer (score 0):

The below program might do the requirement but it is not efficient enough. I am just giving a rough example. Hope this helps.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void display(char** temp,int LinesWritten);

int main()
{
FILE *fp;

char *buffer  = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*101); // 101 is just an assumption. dynamic size may be decided 
char **result = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*10); // 10 is just an assumption. dynamic size may be decided
int LinesWritten = 0;
char **temp = result;
char **freetemp = result;

if((fp = fopen("file.txt","r"))==NULL)
{
        printf("Error while opening file\n");
        exit(1);
}

while((fgets(buffer,100,fp))&&(!(feof(fp))))     //assuming that 100 characters will be read into the buffer
{
        if(*result = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*10))
        {
                sprintf(*result,"%s%s",buffer,"test");
                *result++;
                LinesWritten++;
        }
}

fclose(fp);

display(temp,LinesWritten);

if(freetemp!=NULL)
{
        free(freetemp);
}

return 0;

}

void display(char** temp,int LinesWritten)
{

for(int i=0;i<LinesWritten;i++)
{
        printf("%s\n",*temp);
        *temp++;
}

return;
}
```

Comment: 1) This causes a memory leak. 2) You need to remove newline from the input line. 3) `malloc(sizeof(char)*10)` : Because it is smaller than the row buffer, it causes buffer overrun. 4) `!(feof(fp))` : It malfunctions when there is no newline in the last line. This is superfluous and should be deleted.