# Pass data via a pipe to a C program

Tags: c, bash

I want to send data through a pipe to a simple c program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
char message[100000];
scanf("%s", message);
printf("%s", message);
return 0;
}
```

For instance, I want to print to the terminal all the data from /etc/passwd. To do so, I type:

```
cat /etc/passwd | ./my_c_program
```

But it is not working, it just prints "##".

Comment: `scanf` stops at whitespace.

Comment: `scanf` is good for simple parsing. The pattern you want is, I think, `fgets` in a loop.

Comment: Or fread followed by zero termination

Comment: ... so when I run your program (in Windows console) as `dir | my_c_program` the output is simply `Volume`.

Comment: @WeatherVane - `cat /etc/passwd | ./my_c_program` in Windows console??

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin the equivalent as commented. C behaves the same.

Comment: Oh, OK, yes, any term or xterm on Linux makes sense. I was thinking "windows would be dumbfounded by `cat`, `/etc/passwd`, etc...".

Comment: I guess the questioner got it sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the easiest way is to use **`getline()`**. The `man` page describes the function as below:

> `ssize_t getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream);`
>
> `getline()`  reads  an  entire line from stream, storing the address of the buffer containing the text into `*lineptr`.  The buffer is null-terminated and includes the newline character, if one was found.

By the way, keep in mind this paragraph:

> If `*lineptr` is **set to NULL** and `*n` is **set 0 before the call**, then `getline()` will **allocate a buffer** for storing the line.  **This buffer should  be  freed**  by the user program **even if getline() failed.**

Below a working sample.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv)
{
  char* l = NULL;
  size_t n;
  while (getline(&l,&n, stdin) != -1 )
    {
      printf("%s",l);
    }
  free(l); // don't forget to release the allocated memory
           // mmh, yes, here it's not useful since the program
           // ends.
}
```

This answer is inspired by this [SO reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501338/c-read-file-line-by-line).