# c++ reading file using getline and FILE instead of ifstream

Tags: c++, file, io, getline

I have a `FILE*` object from which I want to read line by line. The most common approach however is to pass a directory to `ifstream` and use `getline(ifstream, line)` in a while loop to read line by line.

However I do not have a directory. I have to work with `FILE*`. Is there a `getline()` that accepts a `FILE*` as parameter? or, in general is there another way in c++ to read lines with `FILE*`

[C read file line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501338/c-read-file-line-by-line)  does not work for me since i'm not on linux.

I was also thinking if an ifstream can accept a `FILE` instead of a directory but I am not sure about this. can anyone confirm?

Comment: There are various other portable solutions in the answers you linked to, what is wrong with those?

Comment: You could try https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/file_descriptor.html#overview

Comment: You could use boost::filesystem::ifstream as an alternative

Comment: @camp0 I would appreciate an example since I am new to this.

Comment: It is not hard to build a getline clone from fgets. A bit of memory allocation and it is done...

Comment: There are `istream`/`istreambuf` implementations floating around that wrap `FILE*`.

Answer (score 2):

```
std::vector<std::string> getFileAsLines(FILE *file) {
  std::vector<std::string> out;
  int currentIn = fgetc(file);
  std::string currentLine;

  while(currentIn != EOF) {
    if (currentIn == '\n') {
      out.push_back(currentLine);
      currentLine = std::string();
    } else {
      currentLine += (char)currentIn;
    }

    currrentIn = fgetc(file);
  }
  out.Push_back(currentLine);
  return out;
}
```

Didnt test it, but the idea should go through

Comment: In your while condition it should be `&&` or `and` not `AND`

Comment: @Narase so as a termination, while(line = getNextLine(File*file) != NULL) should work right? since 'out' is initially empty

Comment: No, an empty string is not NULL since its not a pointer. Looks like youre coming from Java/C#. I edited the function so it returns the whole file as list of lines