# How to read a file line by line into struct?

Tags: c, data-structures, filereader, readfile

I have a file.txt that contains:

```
Marco Beno
Polo
15
Mario
Pollo Pollo
20
```

and struct defined as that:

```
struct person{
char name[15];
char surname[15];
int age;
}
```

now I want to read into this ***struct*** this file line by line, so ***marco beno*** is assigned to ***person.name***,***Polo*** to ***person.surname*** and so on... I have been looking for a solutions but couldn't find related example. The problem is that ***space*** is skipping the reading to next variable so ***Marco*** is name and ***Beno*** is surname. 
However it should look like that: person.name == Marco Beno

Comment: `fscanf` can work in your example. See its [manpage](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fscanf.htm)

Comment: You should include your code so someone can tell you how to deal with the problem you are experiencing.

Comment: I do have a line of code `fscanf(filename, %s %s %d, person1->name, person1->surname, person1->age` and then when I `printf(person1->name)` in the same while loop it prints single words - not a full line.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C read file line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501338/c-read-file-line-by-line)

Comment: not really, as I'm not allowed to use any other library than ASCI C

Answer (score 0):

Rather than reading the file line-by-line, you can use `fscanf` to read three lines (= one data record) at a time like this:

```
while (fscanf(filename, "%[^\n]\n%[^\n]\n%i\n", person1.name, person1.surname, &person1.age) == 3) 
{
    printf("Retrieved data record: name = '%s', surname = '%s', age = %i\n", 
        person1.name, person1.surname, person1.age);
}
```

The format specifier `%[^\n]\n` will read all characters except the newline character (i.e. an entire line including white spaces) and then the newline character itself. This happens twice per data record (for the name and surname), and finally it reads an integer number and the third newline character.

Note that this is just a simple example to explain the idea, and the `person1` structure is overwritten every time. If you need the entire file in memory, you will of course have to store each data record individually (e.g. in an array of `person`).