# How to read and display the contents of a .txt file using C?

Tags: c

How can I write a C program which can read the numbers and strings in a .txt file? I am just able to read a portion of text file till now.

[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()

{
    char c[1000];
    FILE *fptr;
    if ((fptr = fopen("data3.txt", "r")) == NULL) 
    {
        printf("Error! opening file");
        exit(1);
    }

    fscanf(fptr, "%[]", c);
    printf("Data from the file:\n%s", c);
    fclose(fptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C read file line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501338/c-read-file-line-by-line)

Comment: Put `fscanf("%999[]", c);` and print inside a loop

Comment: @pmg still facing the same problem

Comment: `for (;;) { fscanf(fptr, "%999[]", c); printf("Data from the file:\n%s", c); }`

Comment: now my console is blank @pmg

Comment: You have to stop the loop once the file is exhausted.

Comment: would you mind guiding me through that process? @pmg

Comment: `if (fscanf(...) != 1) break;` ... fscanf() returns 1 in your specific case usually, `EOF` (a negative value) when there is an error: and end of file is an error

Comment: Please create an answer or delete the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used another method to solve it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE * txt;

    char ch;
    txt = fopen("nameOfTheFile.txt", "r"); 
    
    if(txt == NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to open the file\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    do 
    {
        ch = fgetc(txt);
        putchar(ch);

    } while(ch != EOF);
    
    fclose(txt);

    return 0;
}
```