# How to best parse comments lines in a file with C

Tags: c

Okay so I'm trying to read in a PPM file (p3 format) and I want to read the comments (which are #s in ppm files).

The problem is that I don't know how to make C do what is in my head, heres what I want it to do.

```
read the file

where # appears, store all characters until the %\n character appears

repeat until all comments are read
```

I understand that I should be using some variations of getc, fgets and fscanf but I don't know how to apply them in this context.

I would put some code up showing what i've tried with getc, fgets and fscanf but to be brutally honest I have no idea how to use any of those functions and none of the info I can find seems to help and I really don't think any of my implementations are even doing anything.

Does anyone /is anyone willing to show me an example of how to parse a line with any of these functions?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine <- Now, start programming ...

Comment: have a look at the getLine function. What could help is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501338/c-read-file-line-by-line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, two-state FSM, reading one character at a time:

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
int ch, state;

for(state=0;; ) {
        ch = getc(stdin);
        if (ch == EOF) break;
        if (state) {
                putc(ch, stdout);
                if (ch == '\n') state=0;
                continue;
                }
        if (ch == '#') state = 1;
        }
return 0;
}
```

---

Using ./a.out <fsm.c

---

```
include <stdio.h>
') state = 1;
```

Comment: Interesting, but how do I apply this to FILE IO as opposed to user IO.

Comment: What is FILE IO? What is user IO ? Is there a difference ?

Comment: what I mean is, I want to fopen a file and then parse through that. Doesn't stdin request user input from the console?

Comment: It would be exactly the same. The advantage of stdin/stdout is that you do not have to open them; they are already opened for you. Now, **you** do your homework.