# How can I read a text file and convert that into a 2D array of characters?

Tags: arrays, c, file

I've tried using the method indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39237609) but I'm unable to pinpoint each character from the array "buffer". My end goal is to make one array for each sentence with one word in each row so I need to first know where each character is.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <time.h>
#define LENGTH 100

bool input(char *file_name, char *phrase)
{
    FILE *file;
    bool file_valid;
    int i, j, k, l;
    file = fopen(file_name, "r");

    if (file != NULL)
    {
        file_valid = true;

        while(fgets(phrase, LENGTH, file))
        {
            printf("%s", phrase);
        }
        printf("\nThe file was loaded succesfully.\n");
        fclose(file);
    }
    else
    {
        file_valid = false;
        printf("\nWe couldn't find a file with the specified name. Closing program.");
    }
}

int main()
{
    char file_name[20], phrase[LENGTH];
    int i, j;

    printf("Please introduce the name of the file: ");
    scanf("%s", file_name);
    input(file_name, phrase);

    return 0;
}
```

There are some variables and headers that aren't necessary atm but I will be using them later on.