# how to print sentences with spaces from a txt?

Tags: c

I'm trying to copy text from a input.txt but programs thinks spaces are new lines. How should I go about this?

my input.txt *(trial)*

```
1. hero
2. angelic
3. hello world
4. demons
```

my source.c

```
int main(void) {

FILE* fread = fopen("C:\\Users\\EXAMPLE\\desktop\\input.txt", "r");

if (fread == NULL) {
    printf("One file wouldn't open!\n");
    return -1;
}

    //this pastes the text from input.txt into the command-line
char line[1000] = "";
while (fscanf(fread, "%s", line) == 1) {
    printf("%s\n", line);
}

fclose(fread);
fclose(fwrite);
```

output

```
1.
hero
2.
angelic
3.
hello
world
4.
demons
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C read file line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501338/c-read-file-line-by-line)

Comment: Preferably, you should use `fgets` instead of `scanf`. `%s` modifier will stop reading at the first whitespace character it encounters, you could use `%[^\n]` instead to read the whole line.

Comment: And you should definitely limit the input length, since your array is of `char [1000]`, `%999[^\n]` should do it.

Comment: @alex01011 you mean `"%999[^\n]%*c"` or with a space before the %:  `" %999[^\n]"` isn't it? Otherwise the newline is not consumed and only the first line is printed.

Comment: Yes, space in front is required you are right.

Comment: Using variables named `fread` and `fwrite` in a function that does file operations feels rather inappropriate, if you ask me

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you do. There is already function implemented to help you in doing this.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE * fp;
    char * line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;

    fp = fopen("C:\\Users\\EXAMPLE\\desktop\\input.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL){
        printf("One file wouldn't open!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
        printf("Retrieved line of length %zu:\n", read);
        printf("%s", line);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    if (line)
        free(line);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Note that [`getline()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) is a POSIX function, not part of the Standard C Library.  That matters since the code appears to be running on Windows, judging from the file's pathname.  Also, there's no need to test `line` before calling `free(line);` — if `line` is still null (unlikely, even if the first input failed because the file was empty), freeing a null pointer is defined behaviour and a no-op.