# Free a NULL pointer

Tags: c, free

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does free(ptr) where ptr is NULL corrupt memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938735/does-freeptr-where-ptr-is-null-corrupt-memory)
>   [Is it good practice to free a NULL pointer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084218/is-it-good-practice-to-free-a-null-pointer-in-c)

I have a question concerning freeing a null pointer.

```
char *p = NULL;
free(p);
```

Could the `free(NULL)` cause a crash?

Or does it depend on the compiler?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938735/does-freeptr-where-ptr-is-null-corrupt-memory

Comment: It is always safe.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084218/is-it-good-practice-to-free-a-null-pointer-in-c for a duplicate question and answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From man page of free

```
void  free(void *ptr);
```

> The free() function deallocates the memory allocation pointed to by
>   ptr. If ptr is a NULL pointer, no operation is performed.

If you want to get confirmation from C manual itself

> The free function causes the space pointed to by ptr to be
>   deallocated, that is, made available for further allocation. If ptr is
>   a null pointer, no action occurs.

See page 313 of [this](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf) document.

Comment: Note that man pages are not a reliable source for the definition of a standard C function, because they might contain for example Posix-specific guarantees that aren't guaranteed for C in general. In this case, the behavior is guaranteed by the C standard too.

Comment: @SteveJessop correct.. I will edit the answer.. eventhough the question is closed..

Comment: this is a classic example of exception handling in the system library!