# how to freeing pointers using macro in c

Tags: c, free

I want to write macro in c code to freeing many pointers like this :

```
FREE(ptr1, ptr2, ptr3, ptr4, ptrx);
```

For me, this is better than

```
 FREE(ptr1); 
 FREE(ptr2);
 FREE(ptr3);
 FREE(ptr4);
 FREE(ptrx);
```

Thanks in advance

Regards,

Comment: This is not better. It is absolutely stupid. -1. It will only confuse every new developer and won't really help anything.

Comment: I believe this is possible with variadic macros, but writing a variadic macro for this is rather overkill. Make sure you're not using a jillion variables where an array or other comparable data structure would be more reasonable.

Comment: are you sure that can't help to reduce the number of line of c code !!!

Comment: @JanHudec why this is a stupid idea. the OP can ask what he wants according to his needs and personally I see it's a good idea to free all pointers in only one call

Comment: You should instead maybe reconsider why you have so many pointers, e.g. using an array of pointers would make it more readable. `for (int i = 0; i < MAX_POINTERS; ++i) free( ptr[i] );`

Comment: Even if it is a bad idea, it is a valid question and I don't see the reason for -1 or even -3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass variable number of arguments in macro. Following code works fine:

```
#define FREE_ALL(...) \
do { \
    int i=0;\
    void *pta[] = {__VA_ARGS__}; \
    for(i=0; i < sizeof(pta)/sizeof(void*); i++) \
    { \
        free(pta[i]); \
    }\
} while(0)
```

Comment: All multiline macros should be enclosed with a do{}while statement. Also using __VA_ARGS__ for anything other than a function parameter is not specified by C standard and the result might vary by different compilers.

Answer (score 5):

Use a function with variable number of function arguments. Header: [stdarg.h](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdarg/).

I had a little fun with the solution.

```
#define FREE( ... ) Free( &free_stop , __VA_ARGS__ , &free_stop )
//takes any number of pointer arguments,(at least one )( can also take NULL which is handled by free )

int free_stop ;

void Free( void* point , ... )  
{
    if( !point )
        return ;

    va_list list ;
    va_start( list , point ) ;

    void* p = va_arg( list , void* ) ;
    while( p != point ) 
    {
        free( p ) ;
        p = va_arg( list , void* ) ;
    }


    va_end( list ) ;

}
```

Usage:

```
FREE( ptr1 , ptr2 , ptr3 ) ;   //don't have to NULL terminate
```

Comment: I want to avoid include new header file "stdarg.h" for that reason I choose user3162146's solution ; thanks

Comment: @self Is it possible to use the address of the Free function instead of the `int free_stop` address like this: `Free( &Free , __VA_ARGS__ , &Free )`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can define a function like:

```
void freeargs(void *ptr1, ...) {
    // code for freeing variable number of arguments until NULL pointer.
}
```

and then the macro:

```
#define FREE(...) freeargs(__VA_ARGS__, NULL)
```

Comment: your solution looks good But it will not work correctly if one of the input pointers is NULL

Comment: And if one of the pointers was already `NULL`, this fails. Maybe it would be useful to have a special value (such as the address of a static variable or such) as a stopping sentinel.

Comment: If you had a NULL pointer among the arguments your original program would crash.

Comment: @MarianV the free of NULL does not cause a crash http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13471749/free-a-null-pointer

Comment: @MarianV may be you have to use another specific stop address like 0xFFFFFFFF but you have to see first if it could be a valid stop address

Comment: Yes. It may be safer to use (for example) the address of freeargs as the last argument `#define FREE(...) freeargs(__VA_ARGS__, freeargs)` or something like @MOHAMED proposes

Comment: @MOHAMED You can always declare a const  global variable and use its address.

Comment: @self I know but the question here what is the safe address to use. I suggested 0xFFFFFFFF but I do not know if it's a valid address

Comment: @MOHAMED ... An address of a global var declared for this purpose is safe to use.

Comment: @self `freeargs` is the address of the function itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a neutral idea.
positive:If you want to free pointers together,it can help.but it seemly doesn't save much things.
negative:if the pointers may free dispersedly,then you should wait them used,which may cause pointers fogetten.
by the way,the macos can be

```
#define FREE(ptr1, ptr2, ptr3, ptr4, ptrx) (free(ptr1);free(ptr2);free(ptr3);free(ptr4);free(ptr5);)
```

Answer (score 0):

use BOOST

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq/for_each.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/tuple/to_seq.hpp>

#define PROC(r, f, elem) f(elem);
#define FREE(...) BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(PROC, free, BOOST_PP_TUPLE_TO_SEQ((__VA_ARGS__)))
```

Comment: @self yes, only need preprocessor.