# How to know last argument of va_list?

Tags: c, optional-parameters, variadic-functions

I'm reading about how to pass optional arguments to function. But I'm unable to understand those. When I see examples, they are confusing and a bit complex. So I just started with a very simple program with what I have understood up to now.

The below program just prints the variables.

```
void print(int x, ...)
{
        va_list ap;
        int i = 4;     // I know I'm passing only 4 opt variables. 
        int num;

        va_start(ap, x);
        while(i--) {         // How to know how many variables came in real time?
                num = va_arg(ap, int);
                printf("%d\n", num);
        }
        va_end(ap);
        return;
}

int main()
{
        print(1,2,3,4,5);
        return 0;

}
```

I don't know above program is right or not. But it's working. When I change the `i` value to `5` printing garbage. How to know how many arguments I got (like `argc` in `main`)?

Comment: Same way you know how many items are in an array you passed to a function; you keep track of it yourself, because C isn't going to do it for you.

Comment: `How to know how many arguments I got (like argc in main)?` - **you don't.** You pass it along with the arguments. Maybe as the first argument. And please **do not** try to follow the "awesome" ideas you've got from the answer below. They're truly, truly horrible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can take a look to [NARGS macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11920577/casting-all-parameters-passed-in-macro-using-va-args)

Adapted to your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

#define NARGS_SEQ(_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,N,...) N
#define NARGS(...) NARGS_SEQ(__VA_ARGS__, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)

#define print(...) fnprint(NARGS(__VA_ARGS__), __VA_ARGS__)

void fnprint(int n, ...)
{
        va_list ap;
        int num;

        va_start(ap, n);
        while (n--) {
                num = va_arg(ap, int);
                printf("%d\n", num);
        }
        va_end(ap);
        return;
}

int main(void)
{
        print(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
        return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:**
If you want to use the same name for macro and function, use () to stop the preprocessor from expanding the function definition:

```
#define print(...) print(NARGS(__VA_ARGS__), __VA_ARGS__)

void (print)(int n, ...) /* Note () around the function name */
{
  ...
```

**EDIT 2:** Another (ugly) method (but without restriction in the number of args) using compound literals (std 99) and `sizeof`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

#define print(...) print(sizeof((int []) {__VA_ARGS__}) / sizeof(int), __VA_ARGS__)

void (print)(int n, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    int num;

    va_start(ap, n);
    while (n--) {
        num = va_arg(ap, int);
        printf("%d\n", num);
    }
    va_end(ap);
    return;
}

int main(void)
{
    print(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
    return 0;
}
```

`print` is expanded to:

```
print(sizeof((int []) {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}) / sizeof(int), 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

But constructions like `print(1, 2, 3, a_var++, 4, 5);` or `print(1, 2, some_func_returning_int(), 4, 5);` evaluates `a_var++` and `some_func_returning_int()` two times, thats a big problem.

Comment: rename `fnprint` to `print`

Comment: sorry I didn't see line `#define print(...) fnprint(NARGS..` line. Thats way I said. Now It's OK. And worked. But I didn't get what NARGS does exactly.

Comment: @SGG, thanks for check this answer, but note that `print` is restricted to `N` args, Joachim's answer (`pass the number of "extra" arguments as the first argument`) doesn't have restrictions

Comment: your code only supports only 9 numbers. If it's more than 9 numbers, segmentation fault will come. right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52655/discussion-between-sgg-and-alter-mann)

Comment: But of course you can increase the number of args, `__VA_ARGS__ ,64, 63,62`

Comment: In the chat the conclusion is: `print(0, 1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 5, 10, 324, 5325, 3525, 532, 12, 313, 321);`
is expanded to:
`print(5325, 0, 1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 5, 10, 324, 5325, 3525, 532, 12, 313, 321);` giving a segmentation fault

Comment: Evaluates params two times, a problem when you use functions instead of constant numbers, see last edit

Comment: @SGG The first method has a limited number of parameters and the seconds only takes a specific type. Here is a solution to both problems: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20993120/2327831 ( shameless self promotion )

Comment: The example only takes void pointers but you can pass anything.

Answer (score 11):

There is no way of knowing how many arguments are passed from inside a variable-argument function, that's why functions such as `printf` are using special format strings that tells the function how many arguments to expect.

Another way is of course to pass the number of "extra" arguments as the first argument, like

```
print(4, 1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Or to have a special value that can't be in the list as last argument, like

```
print(1, 2, 3, 4, -1);
```

---

<strike>You also have to take note that the last non-va argument you pass to the function (the argument named `num` in your case) is not included in the `va_list`, so in your case with the shown code with `4` as hardcoded number of arguments you will *still* print garbage, as you pass `1` for the `num` argument and then three `va_list` arguments.</strike>

Also take care because you use `num` as both argument and a local variable name.

Comment: Hmm... knowledge++; :-)

Comment: Lets say I have 30-40 numbers to pass as optional arguments. So I have count every time? And What if `-1` is the one of the argument?

Comment: @SGG If there is no specific value that can be used as "end of list" sentinel, then you have to pass the count as first (non `va_list`) argument.

Comment: If I give this code to people, and If I say please count the numbers how many you are passing and pass it that as first variable is not good.

Comment: @SGG Maybe not, but you don't have any choice.

Comment: @SGG The function `print` as shown in your question is correct, as long as you only pass four arguments (and you don't want to print `x`).

Answer (score 0):

Another ugly way for both int and strings:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

#define print(...) fnprint("{" # __VA_ARGS__ )

fnprint(char *b) {
    int count = 0, i;
    if (b[1] != '\0') {
        for (i =2; b[i]; i++) {
            if (b[i] == ',')
               count++;
        }
        count++;
    }
    printf("\ncount is %i\n", count);
}

int main(void)
{
        print();
        print("1", "2");
        print(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: your receiving them as `char`.  If I want to manipulate received variables, I have to convert them to particular type. My code will be huge

Comment: this function would be just utility to count then pass this val and VA_ARGS separately to other function:                                 #define print(...) PRINT( COUNTINGFUNCTION("{" # __VA_ARGS__ ), __VA_ARGS__ )