# Deallocating void double pointer

Tags: c++, memory-management

How would I deallocate a void double pointer?

`deallocate(void** ptr)`

This is the case I am trying to test against:

`char* allocated = (char*)allocate_array(sizeof(char), BUFSIZ,0);`

`deallocate_array((void**)&allocated);`

I need to check to see if the ptr is not NULL so here is my attempt:

```
if(ptr != NULL && *ptr != NULL){
      free(*ptr);
}
ptr = NULL;
return;
```

Comment: There is need to check *ptr, [free can handle it being NULL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084218/is-it-good-practice-to-free-a-null-pointer-in-c).

Comment: How was `ptr` allocated?  Do `ptr` and `*ptr` both point to allocations? Are you trying to free both or just one allocation?

Comment: `char* allocated = (char*)allocate_array(sizeof(char), BUFSIZ,0);` 
`deallocate_array((void**)&allocated);`
is the case i'm supposed to test against

Comment: You do not deallocate a pointer, you deallocate the object it points to. (In this case `ptr` is a pointer, `*ptr` is both a pointer and an object being deallocated, and `*(some_unknown_type*)*ptr` is an object being deallocated)

Comment: Don't change your original question. When you edit, you can add additional information, but don't delete your original or all answers given before your edit will no longer make sense...

Comment: Your code violates the strict aliasing rule (`char *` is aliased as `void *`)

Comment: If you are using C++ it would be simpler to pass the ptr to deallocate by reference instead of by value.  That way you don't have to dereference to change the value when you return.

Comment: A "double pointer" is not a thing in C++. What you're playing with here is a "pointer to pointer".

Answer (score 2):

Your try is pretty good. You want to something like this:

```
void deallocate(void **ptr) {
    char *allocated = NULL;
    if (ptr) {
        allocated = *ptr;
    }
    if (allocated) {
        free(allocated);
        *ptr = NULL;
    }
}
```

You will call it like this:

```
deallocate(&allocated);
```

The reason you pass in the address of the pointer is so that you can set the pointer back to null after deallocation.

Comment: error: `assigning to 'char *' from incompatible type 'void *'` during compile

Comment: @MikeHenke: Then you are writing C++. You tagged your question as C.

Comment: There is no need to pass `(void **ptr)` passing `(void *ptr)` is more proper. A copy of the pointer still holds the starting address to the block to be `free`ed.

Comment: Yeah.  You don't have to cast the assignment in deallocate in C.

Answer (score 0):

You may be making this more complicated than need be. There is no reason to pass the *address of* (e.g. `&allocated`) to your `deallocate` function (except to set the value of the original pointer to `NULL` without utilizing a return). You can simply pass a pointer. Yes, the function will receive a copy of that pointer, but it will still contain the *starting address* of the block of memory to be freed. e.g.:

```
void deallocate (void *ptr)
{
    if (!ptr) return;
    free (ptr);
}
```

If your intent was to deallocate and set the value pointed to by the original pointer to `NULL` within your `deallocate` function, then yes, you do need to pass the address of the original so that setting the pointer to `NULL` is reflected back in the calling function (or you could make your function `void *` and return a pointer to the value set to null). Leaving the parameter passed to `deallocate` as a `void` pointer, you could do the following:

```
void deallocate_doubleptr (void *ptr)
{
    if (!ptr || !*(void **)ptr) return;
    free (*(void **)ptr);
    *(void **)ptr = NULL;
}
```

(**note:**, you do not pass a `void **` parameter, you simply pass a `void *` (void) pointer and cast as required within the function. The parameter is still a `void` pointer.)

A short example illustrating the point that both are equivalent, except for the explicit assignment of `NULL`, and guessing at what your `allocate_array` would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void *allocate_array (size_t size, size_t nmemb, int set);
void deallocate (void *ptr);
void deallocate_doubleptr (void *ptr);

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    size_t size  = argc > 1 ? (size_t)strtoul (argv[1], NULL, 10) : 1;
    size_t nmemb = argc > 2 ? (size_t)strtoul (argv[2], NULL, 10) : 128;
    int    set   = argc > 3 ? (int)strtol (argv[3], NULL, 10) : 0;
    char *str = "The quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog.";

    char *allocated = NULL;

    if ((allocated = allocate_array (size, nmemb, set)))
        printf ("\nsuccessfully allocated '%zu' bytes initialized to '%d' ('%c').\n",
                size * nmemb, set, set);

    if (31 < set && set < 127) { /* if filled with printable ASCII */
        allocated[strlen (str)] = 0;                /* nul-terminate */
        printf ("allocated : '%s'\n", allocated);   /* output array */
    }

    strncpy (allocated, str, size * nmemb - 1);     /* copy str to array */
    allocated[size * nmemb - 1] = 0;                /* nul-terminate */

    printf ("allocated : '%s'\n", allocated);       /* output */

#ifdef DEALLOCDBL
    deallocate_doubleptr (&allocated);
    printf ("deallocated all memeory, pointer reinitialized to 'NULL'\n");
#else
    deallocate (allocated);
    printf ("deallocated all memeory.\n");
#endif

    return 0;
}

void *allocate_array (size_t size, size_t nmemb, int set)
{
    if (!size || !nmemb) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid size or number of members.\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    void *memptr = NULL;

    if (set != 0) {
        memptr = malloc (nmemb * size);
        memset (memptr, set, nmemb * size);
    }
    else
        memptr = calloc (nmemb, size);

    if (!memptr) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: virtual memory exhausted.\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return memptr;
}

void deallocate (void *ptr)
{
    if (!ptr) return;
    free (ptr);
    ptr = NULL;
}

void deallocate_doubleptr (void *ptr)
{
    if (!ptr || !*(void **)ptr) return;
    free (*(void **)ptr);
    *(void **)ptr = NULL;
}
```

**Compile**

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -o bin/allocate_deallocate allocate_deallocate.c
```

or

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -DDEALLOCDBL -o bin/allocate_deallocate_dbl allocate_deallocate.c
```

(most compilers should take the same, or very similar options)

**Output**

The output is the same regardless of the implementation called. (e.g. `allocate_deallocate` or `allocate_deallocate_dbl`):

```
$ ./bin/allocate_deallocate 1 64 65

successfully allocated '64' bytes initialized to '65' ('A').
allocated : 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'
allocated : 'The quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog.'
deallocated all memeory.
```

**Memory/Error Check**

```
$ valgrind ./bin/allocate_deallocate 1 64 65
```

or

```
$ valgrind ./bin/allocate_deallocate_dbl 1 64 65

==13759== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==13759== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==13759== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==13759== Command: ./bin/allocate_deallocate
==13759==

successfully allocated '64' bytes initialized to '65' ('A').
allocated : 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'
allocated : 'The quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog.'
deallocated all memeory, pointer reinitialized to 'NULL'
==13759==
==13759== HEAP SUMMARY:
==13759==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13759==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 64 bytes allocated
==13759==
==13759== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==13759==
==13759== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==13759== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```

Look it over and let me know if you have any questions.