# C++: performance, free(null)/delete null and `std::move`

Tags: c++, glibc

I know that calling `free` with a null pointer is a NO-OP, `free` already has a check for that, but it's also true that `free` is a `libc` library function that might have some fixed overhead respect to doing nothing.

My question is, is it worth to consider replacing this:

```
delete ptr;
```

by this?

```
if (ptr)
   delete ptr;
```

First, do `delete` do a null check before forwarding the call to `free`? or do `delete` usually forwards the call in an absolutely transparent way?

If that's the case, we can talk in terms of `free` from now on.

So, is the transformation above worth it in order to avoid a potentially expensive `free` execution that does nothing? In C++ it might be a thing to consider because of `std::move`ing objects around might leave a graveyard of empty objects behind while reaching to its final destination; objects whose destructors will call `free` with null pointers.

Checking the `glibc` source code, I found this:

```
void
free (void *ptr)
{
  struct header *real;

  /* Determine real implementation if not already happened.  */
  if (__glibc_unlikely (initialized <= 0))
    {
      if (initialized == -1)
        return;

      me ();
    }

  /* If this is not the correct program just use the normal function.  */
  if (not_me)
    {
      (*freep) (ptr);
      return;
    }

  /* `free (NULL)' has no effect.  */
  if (ptr == NULL)
    {
      catomic_increment (&calls[idx_free]);
      return;
    }

  // rest of the implementation
```

so calling it looks like not "free" at all; there's stuff below and even an `atomic` increment before the null check, but it's also true that this implementation might be a fallback implementation or something; that's not the first time I'm reading a library function whose actual implementation is done somewhere else, in assembly or something, or there's specialized versions for different archs or whatever.

Comment: Have you tried benchmarking it? What did you find?

Comment: if ptr is null, free is a noop

Comment: @Raildex that's literally my first sentence, that doesn't mean it's execution cost is 0. You have to do the library call (which implies an indirect jump) and also whatever `free` must do before doing the actual check for null.

Comment: *that might have some fixed overhead respect to doing nothing.* Don't guess it. Glibc is open source, you might research there and get answers.

Comment: @gregspears in 64-bits a pointer is surely sent using a register, right?

Comment: This needs to figure out whether doing this null pointer check before the call to `free` incurs less cost than saving the overhead of a function call, given that the overhead of the null pointer check will occur ***every time***.

Comment: @gregspears which C++ compiler on which architecture does not pass pointers in registers?

Comment: @AlanBirtles If I'm not wrong I think the x86-64 calling conventions uses registers for passing primitive types (up to a limit). `free` needs only one argument of 8-bytes long, so the x86-64 calling convention demands it's passed using a register, at least in Linux and Windows, but I think it applies to even more OSs (I think Linux uses the System V calling convention, so it applies to other UNIX OSes as well). But I'm not an expert and I might have misunderstood it.

Comment: Have you considered the penalty for checking a pointer that *isn't* `NULL`, which is perhaps the usual case, rather than code that is structured so you don't know, when you probably have a lot worse inefficiencies than calling `free()` with a `NULL` value?

Comment: @WeatherVane yes, that's right, but I also have very present in mind that objects are `std::move`d A LOT in C++; I could try one day to interpose `free` to measure how many calls are done with null and non-null pointers respectively.

Comment: _Don't worry -- be happy_ This is a micro-optimization (generally not worth it). Don't do it "naked": If you must, use an always inline function: `static inline __attribute__((always_inline)) xfree(void *ptr) { if (ptr) free(ptr); }` Better is to use a macro: `#define XFREE(ptr_) do { free(ptr_); ptr_ = NULL; } while (0)` The macro helps with "double free". But, you're optimizing for a _rare_ case. Do you _plan_ to free lots of null pointers??? If so, you're S/W arch needs rethinking.

Comment: Please stick with *one* language.

Comment: I'm not very good in C++ but is there much need for `malloc()` and `free()` anyway?

Comment: @ABu if you use C++ and need `free` and `malloc` then it is a very bad C++ code

Comment: @WeatherVane Rare, but not unheard of. Usually, it's `new` and `delete` which call object constructors/destructors as needed in conjunction with `malloc/free`

Comment: So if it's rare why bother with such micro-optimisation? There would need to a *lot* of such calls with a `NULL` pointer to affect performance.

Comment: @gulpr Sorry, I write `delete` in code but in my mind there's "free" what is written, since that's what happens under the hood after all, and hence that's what matters. I have improved the question though.

Comment: @ABu I would not even use `new/delete` in modern C++ maybe except in special cases.

Comment: @WeatherVane from an engineering point of view it's not worth considering probably, but curiosity also matters, right? :)

Comment: @ABu rather think about your program algorithm, not this pseudo optimizations

Comment: @gulpr What you literally write doesn't change what actually happens. Even if you use `make_unique` or whatever to avoid explicit calls to `new`, there's still calls to malloc and free under the hood.

Comment: @ABu what takes you to the conclusion that `free` is a problem? Did you profile it?

Comment: @ABu The standard does not say if new/delete call maloc/free (in fact they say they may not, it is not something you can assume).

Comment: `My question is, is it worth to consider replacing this:`: No. Because now you have to also explain to all future readers WHY you are adding the extra code. So if you do this I would expect a huge comment with the brekadown of the explanation (that will only apply to the platforms you have tested on). So I would also expect this to be placed within macros that limit its use to the platform where it actually makes a difference. If you are going to all the trouble to benchmark it you have to benchmark it on all configurations and do the correct thing for each configuration.

Comment: @MartinYork It doesn't "say" as a CYA. Under posix-like environments, it interoperates with C functions that call `malloc/free`. Unless `new/delete` use `mmap/munmap` exclusively, they _must_ call `malloc/free` because they can't call `brk/sbrk` without messing things up

Comment: Related [Is it good practice to free a NULL pointer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084218/is-it-good-practice-to-free-a-null-pointer-in-c)

Comment: @CraigEstey: Even at the lowest level of the memory model uses malloc/free there is no guarantee that each specific call to `new` maps to a call to `malloc()` and each call to `delete` maps to a call to `free()` the implementation may choose to implement its own memory management on top of these low level calls. This is why the standard refers to the storage areas used by malloc/free and new/delete differently.

Comment: @MartinYork Of course we can have per-class `new/delete` operators (that usually call `::new/::delete`). They may implement a "slab allocator" for the given class/object but, ultimately, they get down to a primitive: `::new/::delete` --> `malloc/free`. I guess it's a "hard truth" for those that like to say "there's no such language as c/c++" ;-) Again, if `::new/::delete` use `mmap/munmap`, fine: go for it. Or, do a "toy": `char new_arena[1000000000];` and use that. Otherwise, "all roads lead to malloc" ...

Comment: @CraigEstey I think Martin means that since `new`/`delete` is a language primitive and not a function call, the compiler can implement it as the compiler sees fit. He's not talking about how can users use it, but what the compiler can do with it KNOWING what the operator does according to the standard.

Comment: The wrong glibc source was used. The [check `if (mem == 0) return;`](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/master/malloc/malloc.c#L3363-L3364) is done at very begin. The shown code in the Q looks like some mock function that calls the glibc `free()` through the pointer `freep`.

Comment: @273K Yes that makes much more sense. I was accidentally reading malloc/memusage.c, which also contains an implementation of `free`. I don't know what's the difference though.

Comment: It's described at the top of malloc/memusage.c: *Profile heap and stack memory usage of running program.*

Comment: @OP You have overlooked that `delete` must *also* check for NULL, whether or not it calls `free()` under the hood.

Comment: The implementors of Clang and GCC seem to think that the check before the call `operator delete` is worth it: https://godbolt.org/z/nex4K6qa5

Comment: @chrysante Yes I was exactly doing that in godbolt as well hehe, looking what a call to delete does, and the compiler checks for null beforehand.  That counts as an answer to me, post it if you want.

Comment: @ABu it is not a satisfactory answer, because it may also be a side effect of how the frontends of the compilers work. They also don't add null checks before `operator delete` if not present in the source code: https://godbolt.org/z/88nzYE9ba You should also rephrase your question because `free` and `operator delete` are different unrelated functions and you should ask about calls to `free` or `operator delete` instead of `delete` _expressions_, because in the general case they have to perform a null check anyway before calling destructors.

Comment: @ABu `new` as an operator is just syntax over a function call of some sort (e.g. `__some_low_level_new`). However, some think that `new` as an operator is a language misdesign: [My Rant on C++'s operator new](https://www.scs.stanford.edu/~dm/home/papers/c++-new.html) Again, if `new/delete` _only_ calls anonymous `mmap/munmap`, go for it. But, it can't use `brk/sbrk` without cooperation with the underlying libc. And, under `glibc`, the necessary info to do thread locking around the global state for `sbrk_base` is hidden.

Comment: until you really have a problem with performance I would always suggest to follow the rule: _don't optimize prematuraly_ - instead I would recommand not to use `new` and `delete` direclty anymore but instead use mananged pointers like `shared_ptr` and `unqiue_ptr` they will help you much more when considering maintainance and avoiding bugs (but of 'course, there will be scenarios where even your thoughts might be appropriate)

Comment: @chrysante [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78053187/c-performance-freenull-delete-null-and-stdmove#comment137603121_78053187) is not a good example. An overloaded operator `delete` or a custom `Deleter` are not required to behave like the standard library deallocation. Moreover, `int` is oversimplified example. If it was not `int`, the smart pointers could call `~T` before the deallocator and `p != nullptr` is required.

Answer (score 2):

> First, do delete do a null check before forwarding the call to free?

`delete` never directly calls `free`. `delete` calls some deallocation function, i.e. some function with name `operator delete`. The global replaceable `operator delete` overloads have a library implementation that in some suitable way deallocate memory obtained by the corresponding `operator new`. There is no guarantee that it will use `free` for this or how it will use `free`.

The global `::operator delete(void*)` is replaceable in any translation unit. Therefore the compiler is not able to see through it or inline it.

Generally a `delete` expression must always implicitly do a null pointer check anyway, because if a null pointer is passed, then no destructor may be called. If the destructor is trivial or the compiler can inline it to see that it won't do anything, then of course this implicit check might be optimized away.

Whether or not the deallocation function will be called if a null pointer is provided is up to the compiler. So it may or may not be that the compiler performs an implicit null pointer check before calling the deallocation function regardless of your explicit one.

A quick test on godbolt suggests to me that at least both GCC and Clang always emit an implicit null pointer check before calling the deallocation function anyway. So your added explicit check can't positively affect performance.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is, is it worth to consider replacing this:

```
delete ptr;
// by this?
if (ptr)
   delete ptr;
```

Emphatically: **NO**.

1: This is a micro optimization.

Sure; you may gain something on your specific system (you may be able to prove that). But that does not mean your optimization is going to hold for anything but the particular system you are currently on.

Not only is the optimization bound to your current system, but the current version of the compiler and the current version of the standard library you are using.

So if you do this, you have to then enclose your `if (ptr)` between some macros that validate that you are building for a very specific implementation and over time you will then expand that for every system you can prove it for.

2: Every engineer that comes after you and reads the code is going to go: **WHAT IS THIS**. Why was the last person doing this micro optimization. So you then have to include detailed comments explaining **WHY** you have done it and provide the appropriate data the proves it is worth while.

Unless you see some significant improvement, the next person is simply going to delete it because the maintenance cost for subsequent engineers is simply not worth it (as they have to parse and understand the comment, I don't believe that and test it for themselves).

---

With no data to back me up. I would assume that the cost of doing the testing and the extra cognitive cycles used by subsequent engineers maintaining the code will far exceed any improvements you receive for the full lifetime of the code.

**EVEN IF I FOUND A SIGNIFICANT IMPROVEMENT,** the answer is still **no**. But in this situation, my course of action would take the data to the people that write the standard library and/or compiler and get the appropriate changes done at the compiler level.