# Why we don't have to free the embedded pointer of a struct in C

Tags: c

I have seen the following [code](http://www.apibook.com/blog/),

```
/* stack.c */
typedef struct Stack *StackPtr;

struct Stack
{
    int *mStack;
    int mCurSize;
};

StackPtr StackCreate()
{
    return (StackPtr) calloc(sizeof(struct Stack), 1);
}

void StackDestroy(StackPtr stack)
{
    if (stack)
    {
        free(stack);
    }
}

void StackPush(StackPtr stack, int val)
{
    if (! stack)
        return;

    if (stack->mStack)
    {
        int newsize = stack->mCurSize + 1;
        int *newptr = realloc(stack->mStack, sizeof(struct Stack)*newsize);
        if (newptr)
        {
            stack->mStack = newptr;
            stack->mStack[newsize-1] = val;
            stack->mCurSize = newsize;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        stack->mStack = malloc(sizeof(struct Stack));
        if (stack->mStack)
        {
            stack->mStack[0] = val;
            stack->mCurSize = 1;
        }
    }
}

int StackPop(StackPtr stack)
{
    if (! StackIsEmpty(stack))
    {
        return stack->mStack[--stack->mCurSize];
    }
    return 0;
}


void StackDestroyMyWay(StackPtr stack) // This is my understanding
{
    if (stack)
    {
        if (stack->mStack)
            free(stack->mStack);
        free(stack);
    }
}

int StackIsEmpty(const StackPtr stack)
{
    return stack == NULL || stack->mCurSize == 0;
}

/* main.c */
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /* Create a new stack */
    StackPtr stack = StackCreate();
    int val;

    /* push and pop a value to the stack */
    printf( "Empty: %d\n", StackIsEmpty(stack));
    StackPush(stack, 10);
    printf("Empty: %d\n", StackIsEmpty(stack));
    val = StackPop(stack);
    printf("Popped off: %d\n", val);
    printf("Empty: %d\n", StackIsEmpty(stack));

    /* clean up the stack */
    StackDestroy(stack);
    return 0;
}
```

**Question**> I assume the original StackDestory is implemented correctly but I don't understand why we don't have to free `stack->mStack` explicitly.

Comment: I think your way is the correct way.  Given what you have shown us mStack will leak unless explicitly freed.

Comment: I think you have to, and original implementation has a memory leak. Unless it is freed somewhere in the code that you don't show :)

Comment: I think `StackDestroyMyWay()` is correct too. Note, however, that [you don't have to check for null before `free()`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1912325/10077). So you could just say, `if (stack) { free(stack->mStack); free(stack);}`.

Comment: For each malloc/realloc/calloc, you need one call to free. It's a 1-1 correspondance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually you **do** have to free `mStack` *somewhere* or you will leak memory. If `StackDestroy` doesn't do it for you, you'll have to do it yourself later.

When designing an API that allocates and frees stuff think of a few things:

- Did the client allocate the object ? Perhaps he should also free it. Is it possible he passed an object that wasn't obtained via `malloc` ?
- Can the client do useful things with the object beyond the demise of our object ?

In your case the client doesn't even know about the existence of `mStack` (technically you could use opaque objects) so, since *you* allocate it, you should also free it.

Comment: So you think the function `StackDestroyMyWay` is implemented correctly?

Comment: @q0987: I think everyone does so, unless there are some details that you are not aware about...