# Memory leak in assigning pointers

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory-leaks

temp = p_long; is showing memory leak. I am not sure how it is memory leak.

```
long *temp = NULL; 
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
  if (i < 3) {
     long *p_long = new long;

     if ( p_long ) {
        if ( 0 == *p_long ) {
           flag = true;
        } else if ( 1 == *p_long ) {
           temp = p_long;                    -----> showing memory leak here
           continue;
        }
     }
  }
}

if (temp)
delete temp;
```

Thanks.

Comment: You are calling `new` and not calling `delete`.

Comment: but temp is already NULL, not pointing to anything. how come it can be memory leak ?

Comment: My first comment was wrong, sorry. I edited it.

Comment: if(temp!=null) delete temp;

Comment: Its a for loop; so the second time loop comes to temp=p_long; the first new assignment is leaked already

Comment: Sorry I have missed delete statement

Comment: But the point is that you are not always deleting the dynamically allocated memory.

Comment: Delete already checks for NULL.  You don't need to check for it explicitly.

Comment: @Anand Pointers to memory are somewhat like tickets to pick your coat when you exit the disco. If you lose your ticket, you cannot pick your coat. If you take your ticket and erase it so that it no longer shows the number of your coat, this does not mean that you're _not_ losing it. To not lose it you need to actually keep pointing to that number, the number which _can_ possibly be used to access your coat. This number is the value of the address where you allocated memory, and which was returned to you by new.

Comment: Inspired by @DanielDaranas If you overwrite the ticket with some other number, before using it to pick your coat, your coat wont vanish in thin air. Your ticket might be overwritten to point to possibly some other coat, but your previous coat is orphaned without any ticket to identify it.

Answer (score 2):

You are not freeing up the heap allocation `long *p_long = new long;` Considering that it is a `for` loop, you will have orphaned some memory blocks (`new`ed, but no pointers referencing them anymore for `delete`-ion.)

You have to free `p_long` in the appropriate part of the loop if it is not assigned to `temp`. Your `continue` statement is redundant (maybe you meant `break`?). Also, the modern version of `NULL` is `nullptr`.

Another point is that your `if ( p_long )` check is basically only going to be `NULL` in the case that your current `new` heap allocator for that type (`long`) had problems allocating (e.g. out of memory), and that the following `if ( 0 == *p_long )` is checking that the newly allocated `long` was automatically initialised with a value of `0`. AFAIK this is not the case, since in C++, you only pay in performance for what you need. The value is undefined (in reality it will probably be the existing, untampered value at that memory address).

Answer (score 0):

```
long *temp = NULL; 
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
  if (i < 3) {
     long *p_long = new long;

     if ( p_long ) {
        if ( 0 == *p_long ) {
           flag = true;
        } else if ( 1 == *p_long ) {
           if(temp)
              delete temp; -----> leaked memory freed here
           temp = p_long;                   
           continue;
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Anand 1) it still leaks, 2) you don't have to check against `NULL` before calling delete.

Comment: You don't even have to do that. You can just call `delete temp;` without any checks.

Comment: Thanks juanchopanza, one more thing, i am deleting at last also, will that cause any problem ?

Comment: I am deleting temp when "for" loop ends.

Answer (score 0):

First time when you enter the `for` loop `temp` is `NULL` but in later iterations, you allocate dynamic memory to the pointer.

```
long *p_long = new long;
```

And in some iterations you just overwrite the address contained in the pointer. You lose track of the memory allocated using `new`. This does not mean it will automatically get freed. The memory is still allocated, just that you lost the pointer to it.

```
temp = p_long;
```

You need something like,

```
else if ( 1 == *p_long ) 
{
     delete temp; -----> leaked memory freed here. 
     temp = p_long;                   
continue;
}
```

This will delete the allocated memory before you assign a new allocated memory address to `temp`.

Note: [delete is safe to use on NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190703/is-it-safe-to-delete-a-null-pointer) too

Comment: I dont think `if ( 1 == *p_long )` is what he wants to do. Maybe you mean `if (p_long)`. Dereferencing an unchecked pointer can be dangerous (in this case it could be `nullptr`). non-null is not the same as `==1`.

Comment: @PreetKukreti Actually I wanted to indicate use `delete temp` within the `else if block` . The OP is already making a check for `NULL` pointer in `if(p_long)`