# Test answer is wrong yes? It will not crash as we delete NULL pointer which is safe

Tags: c++

Consider the following code:

```
template<class T> void Kill(T *& objPtr)
{
   delete objPtr;
   objPtr = NULL;
}
class MyClass
{
};
void Test()
{
   MyClass *ptr = new MyClass();
   Kill(ptr);
   Kill(ptr);
}
```

Invoking Test() will cause which of the following?

**Answer: Code will Crash or Throw and Exception**

Test answer is wrong yes? It will not crash as we delete NULL pointer which is safe.

Comment: You're correct. I'd guess the test answer was originally written assuming the pointer was passed by value, not reference (or, it was just written by somebody who didn't know what they were doing).

Comment: The definition of `NULL` is not shown, and it just *could* be something ridiculous instead of standard `NULL`. Without this one can only say that it's very *likely* (but not proved) that the test answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, the test answer is wrong.

The first `Kill` calls `delete`, and set the pointer (passed by reference) to `NULL`
The second `Kill` calls `delete` on a null pointer, [which is safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190703/is-it-safe-to-delete-a-null-pointer).

**Note:**

As per Cheers and hth. - Alf commented, this is assuming `NULL` is the usual null pointer, `0`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is safe to delete a null pointer however I dont think you need to call the delete twice as `delete` performs the check anyway. Also I would recommend you to use use smart pointers like `unique_ptr<T>` which take care of deletion.