# Is deleting a null pointer in C++ considered undefined behaviour?

Tags: c++, c++11, undefined-behavior, c++14, null-pointer

Consider the following piece of code:

```
int main() {
  int *i = nullptr;
  delete i;
}
```

Questions:

1. Is deleting a null pointer considered undefined behaviour?
2. Did something changed in C++11 or C++14?

Comment: This question has a [zillion duplicates](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=c%2B%2B+delete+null+pointer+site%3Astackoverflow.com)...

Comment: @40two So unclear that you need to search for *c++ delete null pointer* to find them :P

Comment: you did have different spellings re "NULL pointer" and "null pointer". I made both of them say "null pointer", which is the technical correct spelling.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is deleting a NULL pointer in C++ considered undefined behaviour?

No, this is perfectly legal operation.

From **N3242**, **[expr.delete]**

> the value of the operand of delete may be a null pointer
>   value

Comment: It's quoted in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4190733/207421).