# Dealing with accessing NULL pointer

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, nullpointerexception, null

In my class, I've got - inter alia - a pointer:

```
Class GSM
{
//...
private:
    char *Pin;
//...
}
```

My constructor initialize it as:

```
GSM::GSM()
{
//...
    Pin = NULL; 
//...
}
```

Now, I want to set default value ("1234") to my PIN. I tried very simple way:

```
bool GSM::setDefaultValue()
{
    lock();
    Pin = "0";
    for (uint8 i =0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        Pin[i] = i+1;
    }
    unlock();
    return true;
}
```

But it didn't work. When I run my program (I use Visual Studio 2010) there is an error:

```
Access violation writing location 0x005011d8
```

I tried to remove line

```
Pin = "0";
```

But it didn't help.  I have to initialize it as NULL in constructor. It's part of a larger project, but I think, the code above is what makes me trouble. I'm still pretty new in C++/OOP and sometimes I still get confused by pointers.

What should I do to improve my code and the way I think?
EDIT: As requested, I have to add that I can't use std::string. I'm trainee at company, project is pretty big (like thousands of files) and I did not see any std here and I'm not allowed to use it.

Comment: You need to make `Pin` point to a `char` array you can write to. BTW this has absolutely nothing to do with OOP.

Comment: Why are you ignoring your compiler warnings and coming straight to Stack Overflow? There's tons of automated diagnostics that could help you without requiring human attention.

Comment: Why aren't you using a `std::string`, or a `boost::optional<std::string>` if you need to differentiate having no string from an empty string?  Anyway... if you want to use a pointer you need to point it at some `new`-ed - or perhaps a class-member character array - before you try to overwrite it.

Comment: I'm not using std::string because I'm not allowed to. The whole program is constructed without it, and it's much bigger (like ~700 Mb) and superiors (I'm trainee student ATM) said not to use std::string.  
If someone is disgusted about not so pro question, may vote it down. I like to speak with human when I can't understand compiler, because I'm human too.

Comment: That's OK for learning. There are also systems where one can't really use the standard library anyway. But you could add that information to the question to make it clear.

Comment: @Kappa: Then ask what string type they **do** use. For projects that have been around for 20 years (not unusual with C++), it's possible that they may be using their own `String` class. But if they're not using any string class, then you should learn from this assignment what _not_ to do.

Answer (score 4):

You need to give the `Pin` some memory. Something like this:

```
Pin = new char[5];  // To make space for terminating `\0`;
for(...)
{
   Pin[i] = '0' + i + 1;
}
Pin[4] = '\0';      // End of the string so we can use it as a string.

...
```

You should then use `delete [] Pin;` somewhere too (Typically in the destructor of the class, but depending on how it's used, it may be needed elsewhere, such as assignment operator, and you need to also write a copy-constructor, see [Rule Of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29)).

In proper C++, you should use `std::string` instead, and you could then do:

```
Class GSM
{
//...
private:
    std::string Pin;
....

Pin = "0000";
for (uint8 i =0; i < 4; ++i)
{
    Pin[i] += i+1;
}
```

Using `std::string` avoids most of the problems of allocating/deallocating memory, and "just works" when you copy, assign or destroy the class - because the `std::string` implementation and the compiler does the work for you.

Comment: The `delete` should appear in the destructor, should it not?  I suppose it might be unset at other times too; as long as the pointer (`Pin`) is set to null after the memory is released, that won't cause any trouble.

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate a block of memory to store "1234". This memory block will be pointed by your `Pin` pointer.
You can try:

```
bool GSM::setDefaultValue()
{
    lock();
    Pin = new char[4];
    for (uint8 i =0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        Pin[i] = '0' + (i + 1);
    }
    unlock();
    return true;
}
```

As you have allocated dynamicaly a memory block, you should always release it when you don't need it anymore. To do so, you should add a destructor to your class:

```
GSM::~GSM()
{
    delete [] Pin;
}
```

Comment: Because he wants "1234", not "0123". You can also modify your for loop to achieve the same thing.

Comment: You should add a note that the class now requires a destructor.  It might also be better to allocate an extra character to allow the string to be null terminated — and then null terminate it.

Comment: For the destructor I agree, for the string, if he only need to store 4 char and will check PIN correctness checking for these 4 chars, then I think the null terminated string is not necessary (He did not say he need to store a string, so I assume an array of char is enough).

Comment: No need to add `if (Pin != NULL)` - delete is guaranteed to handle NULL pointers. It may not matter much in this instance, but if you have 1000 classes, that all do that, it's another 2-3000 instructions that aren't needed (because inside `delete` itself, the same check is made)

Comment: You don't need to test for non-null-ness of `Pin`; you can safely delete a null pointer (see [Is it safe to delete a NULL pointer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190703/is-it-safe-to-delete-a-null-pointer/)).  While I will grant you that the question didn't say it needed a null-terminated string, I think it would be more sensible to assume that one was needed.  However, it is your answer.

Comment: Did not know for delete checking NULL pointer. I have edited my answer.

Comment: While you're at it, your class now has a default copy constructor which does the wrong thing. You might want to ` = delete` it, as well as deleting the assignment operator for the same reason (or implement it, of course). `std::string` just works.

Answer (score 0):

## Simple answer:

Instead of using the heap (`new` `delete`) just allocate space in your class for the four character pin:

```
Class GSM
{
//...
private:
    char Pin[5];
//...
}
```

The length is fixed at 5 (to allow space for 4 characters and terminating `null` (`'\0'`), but as long as you only need to store a maximum of 4 characters, you are fine.

Of course, if you want to make it easy to change in the future:

```
Class GSM
{
//...
private:
    const int pin_length = 4;
    char Pin[pin_length+1];
//...
}
```

Your function to set the value will then look like:

```
bool GSM::setDefaultValue()
{
    lock();
    for (char i = 0; i < pin_length; ++i)
    {
        Pin[i] = i+1;
    }
    Pin[pin_length]=0;
    unlock();
    return true;
}
```

or even:

```
bool GSM::setDefaultValue()
{
    lock();
    strcpy(Pin,"1234");  //though you would have to change this if the pin-length changes.
    unlock();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: A `const int` would be better than a preprocessor definition, given the lack of scoping with the latter.  You've left room for a NUL (which is `\0` rather than `/0`) but not added one in `setDefaultValue()`.