# Should I delete origin pointer in operator assignment function?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, assignment-operator

I have write following demo code to learn copy constructor and assignment operator. However there is a little confuse. I was told to delete pointers in assignment operator and allocate new address to the `data`. However I can only make my code work delete that line. I have taken [this](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/911-the-copy-constructor-and-overloading-the-assignment-operator/) page as a reference, but it only shows the example of int while not the `int*`. How can I solve this problem?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <boost/smart_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>

using namespace boost;

class ClassOne
{
public:
    ClassOne():data(NULL) {}
    ClassOne(int data_param):data(NULL)
    {
        init(data_param);
        std::cout << "construct" << std::endl;
    }

    virtual ~ClassOne()
    {
        if (data) {
            delete data;
        }
        data = NULL;
    }

    ClassOne(const ClassOne& rhs){
        std::cout<< "copy " <<std::endl;
        data = NULL;
        init(*rhs.data);
    }

    ClassOne& operator = (const ClassOne& rhs){
        std::cout<< "assign " <<std::endl;
        int* p_old = rhs.data;
        data = new int(*p_old);
        //delete p_old;            // I have to delete this line to make my code work
        return *this;
    }

    void init(int data_param)
    {
        if (data) {
            delete data;
        }
        data = new int(data_param);
    }

private:
    int* data;
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    ClassOne c1(10);
    ClassOne c2(c1);       // call copy constructor
    ClassOne c3;
    c3 = c1;               // call assignment function
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int* p_old = rhs.data;` should be `int* p_old = data;`

Comment: FYI, [it's safe to call `delete` on a `NULL` pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190703/is-it-safe-to-delete-a-null-pointer) (i.e., you don't need to do `if (data)` before calling `delete`).

Comment: And `data = new int(*p_old);` should be `data = new int(*rhs.data);`

Comment: If you have the assignment `a = b`, would you expect `b` to be modified?

Comment: I would humbly suggest using smart pointers and nullptr...

Comment: @JamesAdkison Thanks for your advice.

Comment: @gilgamash  I am learning boost.shared_ptr now. And I misunderstand some keypoints. And thank you for your advice. Later I will learn C++ 11 features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to delete the other object's `data` member, when you are meant to delete your own (`this`) object's current `data` member instead.  What you probably want is this:

```
ClassOne& operator = (const ClassOne& rhs){
    std::cout<< "assign " <<std::endl;
    delete data;               // delete your own old data
    data = new int(*rhs.data); // clone the rhs's data
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Oh, I made a mistake. I misunderstand something, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your code fail because you are double deleting something: you delete the pointer in the copy assignment and in the destructor. Deleting a pointer don't make it null, that's why it passes the if in your destructor. (By the way, you don't need to check the pointer to be null before deleting it, `delete` does the check anyway)

I would recommend copy assignment to not alter the `rhs` variable, as deleting the `data` pointer can easily lead to memory access. I would rather implement a move constructor and assignment to make this behaviour explicit. I would remove copy constructor and assignment and add these function:

```
ClassOne(const ClassOne&) = delete;
ClassOne& operator=(const ClassOne&) = delete;

ClassOne(ClassOne&& rhs) {
    std::swap(data, rhs.data);
}

ClassOne& operator=(ClassOne&& rhs) {
    std::swap(data, rhs.data);
}
```

That would require `std::move` to be call on assignment.

Alternatively, you can implement a non-stealing copy constructor. That would require that youto deep copy the data pointer (copying the content instead of the pointer)

```
ClassOne(const ClassOne& rhs) {
    if (!data) {
        data = new int;
    }
    *data = *(rhs.data);
}

ClassOne& operator=(const ClassOne& rhs) {
    if (!data) {
        data = new int;
    }
    *data = *(rhs.data);
}
```