# Deep copy constructor - dynamic array inside a class C++ Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()

Tags: c++, memory-management, constructor, copy-constructor

I wanted to write a simple class to represent a point A(x,y). However, I have some problems with copy constructor. It gives me `invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()` error when trying analyze my code with `valigrind`. Please, take a look:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

class Point
{
private :
    int *coord;
public:
    Point();
    Point(int x, int y);
    Point(const Point& p);
    ~Point();
    void printpoint();

};

Point::Point()
{
    coord = new int[2];
    coord[0] = 0;
    coord[1] = 0;
}

Point::Point(int x, int y)
{
    coord = new int[2];
    coord[0] = x;
    coord[1] = y;
}

Point::Point(const Point& p)
{
    if (this != &p)
    {
        if(coord != NULL)
        {
            delete[] coord;
            coord = NULL;
        }
        coord = new int[2];
        coord[0] = p.coord[0];
        coord[1] = p.coord[1];
    }
}

Point::~Point()
{
    if(coord != NULL)
    {
        delete[] coord;
        coord = NULL;
    }
}

void Point::printpoint()
{
    std::cout << "Point (" << coord[0] << "," << coord[1] << ")\n";
}


int main()
{
    Point p1;
    p1.printpoint();

    Point *p2 = new Point();
    p2->printpoint();

    Point p3(3,4);
    p3.printpoint();

    Point *p4 = new Point(6,7);
    p4->printpoint();

    Point *p5 = &p1;
    p5->printpoint();

    Point *p6 = p4;
    p6->printpoint();

    Point *p7 = new Point(p3);
    p7->printpoint();

    Point p8 = Point(p3);
    p8.printpoint();

    Point p9 = p1;
    p9.printpoint();

    Point p10 = *p4;
    p10.printpoint();

    Point p11(p1);
    p11.printpoint();

    Point p12(*p6);
    p12.printpoint();

    Point *p13 = new Point(*p7);
    p13->printpoint();

    delete p2;
    delete p4;
    delete p5;
    delete p6;
    delete p7;
    delete p13;

    return 0;
}
```

And the valgrind's output:

```
==3978== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==3978== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==3978== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==3978== Command: ./Untitled2
==3978== 
Point (0,0)
Point (0,0)
Point (3,4)
Point (6,7)
Point (0,0)
Point (6,7)
==3978== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==3978==    at 0x400A92: Point::Point(Point const&) (Untitled2.cpp:36)
==3978==    by 0x400C94: main (Untitled2.cpp:82)
==3978== 
Point (3,4)
==3978== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==3978==    at 0x400A92: Point::Point(Point const&) (Untitled2.cpp:36)
==3978==    by 0x400CBD: main (Untitled2.cpp:85)
==3978== 
==3978== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==3978==    at 0x400A9E: Point::Point(Point const&) (Untitled2.cpp:38)
==3978==    by 0x400CBD: main (Untitled2.cpp:85)
==3978== 
==3978== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==3978==    at 0x4C2C7F2: operator delete[](void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3978==    by 0x400AAE: Point::Point(Point const&) (Untitled2.cpp:38)
==3978==    by 0x400CBD: main (Untitled2.cpp:85)
==3978== 
==3978== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==3978==    at 0x4C2C83C: operator delete[](void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3978==    by 0x400AAE: Point::Point(Point const&) (Untitled2.cpp:38)
==3978==    by 0x400CBD: main (Untitled2.cpp:85)
==3978==  Address 0x602088 is in the Data segment of /home/kasiula/Dropbox/STH/codz/Untitled2
==3978== 
Point (3,4)
==3978== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==3978==    at 0x400A92: Point::Point(Point const&) (Untitled2.cpp:36)
==3978==    by 0x400CE2: main (Untitled2.cpp:88)
==3978== 
==3978== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==3978==    at 0x400A9E: Point::Point(Point const&) (Untitled2.cpp:38)
==3978==    by 0x400CE2: main (Untitled2.cpp:88)
==3978== 
==3978== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==3978==    at 0x4C2C7F2: operator delete[](void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3978==    by 0x400AAE: Point::Point(Point const&) (Untitled2.cpp:38)
==3978==    by 0x400CE2: main (Untitled2.cpp:88)
==3978== 
==3978== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==3978==    at 0x4C2C83C: operator delete[](void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3978==    by 0x400AAE: Point::Point(Point const&) (Untitled2.cpp:38)
==3978==    by 0x400CE2: main (Untitled2.cpp:88)
==3978==  Address 0x1 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==3978== 
Point (0,0)
==3978== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==3978==    at 0x400A92: Point::Point(Point const&) (Untitled2.cpp:36)
==3978==    by 0x400D01: main (Untitled2.cpp:91)
==3978== 
==3978== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==3978==    at 0x400A9E: Point::Point(Point const&) (Untitled2.cpp:38)
==3978==    by 0x400D01: main (Untitled2.cpp:91)
==3978== 
==3978== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==3978==    at 0x4C2C7F2: operator delete[](void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3978==    by 0x400AAE: Point::Point(Point const&) (Untitled2.cpp:38)
==3978==    by 0x400D01: main (Untitled2.cpp:91)
==3978== 
==3978== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==3978==    at 0x4C2C83C: operator delete[](void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3978==    by 0x400AAE: Point::Point(Point const&) (Untitled2.cpp:38)
==3978==    by 0x400D01: main (Untitled2.cpp:91)
==3978==  Address 0x601de8 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==3978== 
Point (6,7)
==3978== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==3978==    at 0x400A92: Point::Point(Point const&) (Untitled2.cpp:36)
==3978==    by 0x400D23: main (Untitled2.cpp:94)
==3978== 
==3978== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==3978==    at 0x400A9E: Point::Point(Point const&) (Untitled2.cpp:38)
==3978==    by 0x400D23: main (Untitled2.cpp:94)
==3978== 
==3978== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==3978==    at 0x4C2C7F2: operator delete[](void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3978==    by 0x400AAE: Point::Point(Point const&) (Untitled2.cpp:38)
==3978==    by 0x400D23: main (Untitled2.cpp:94)
==3978== 
==3978== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==3978==    at 0x4C2C83C: operator delete[](void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3978==    by 0x400AAE: Point::Point(Point const&) (Untitled2.cpp:38)
==3978==    by 0x400D23: main (Untitled2.cpp:94)
==3978==  Address 0x53611a8 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==3978== 
Point (0,0)
==3978== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==3978==    at 0x400A92: Point::Point(Point const&) (Untitled2.cpp:36)
==3978==    by 0x400D42: main (Untitled2.cpp:97)
==3978== 
==3978== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==3978==    at 0x400A9E: Point::Point(Point const&) (Untitled2.cpp:38)
==3978==    by 0x400D42: main (Untitled2.cpp:97)
==3978== 
==3978== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==3978==    at 0x4C2C7F2: operator delete[](void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3978==    by 0x400AAE: Point::Point(Point const&) (Untitled2.cpp:38)
==3978==    by 0x400D42: main (Untitled2.cpp:97)
==3978== 
==3978== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==3978==    at 0x4C2C83C: operator delete[](void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3978==    by 0x400AAE: Point::Point(Point const&) (Untitled2.cpp:38)
==3978==    by 0x400D42: main (Untitled2.cpp:97)
==3978==  Address 0xffefffb50 is on thread 1's stack
==3978==  in frame #2, created by main (Untitled2.cpp:63)
==3978== 
Point (6,7)
==3978== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==3978==    at 0x400A92: Point::Point(Point const&) (Untitled2.cpp:36)
==3978==    by 0x400D6A: main (Untitled2.cpp:100)
==3978== 
Point (3,4)
==3978== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==3978==    at 0x4C2C2BC: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3978==    by 0x400DC5: main (Untitled2.cpp:105)
==3978==  Address 0xffefffae0 is on thread 1's stack
==3978==  in frame #1, created by main (Untitled2.cpp:63)
==3978== 
==3978== Invalid read of size 8
==3978==    at 0x400B06: Point::~Point() (Untitled2.cpp:49)
==3978==    by 0x400DD6: main (Untitled2.cpp:106)
==3978==  Address 0x5a1c180 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 8 free'd
==3978==    at 0x4C2C2BC: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3978==    by 0x400DAC: main (Untitled2.cpp:104)
==3978== 
==3978== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==3978==    at 0x4C2C2BC: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3978==    by 0x400DDE: main (Untitled2.cpp:106)
==3978==  Address 0x5a1c180 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 8 free'd
==3978==    at 0x4C2C2BC: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3978==    by 0x400DAC: main (Untitled2.cpp:104)
==3978== 
==3978== 
==3978== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3978==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3978==   total heap usage: 15 allocs, 22 frees, 120 bytes allocated
==3978== 
==3978== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==3978== 
==3978== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==3978== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==3978== ERROR SUMMARY: 25 errors from 25 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: Why are you making `point` so complication? It only needs to store two ints! Why use dynamic memory for this?

Comment: Note: You do not need to check if your pointer is `NULL` before `delete`. Calling `delete` on `NULL` is OK (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190703/is-it-safe-to-delete-a-null-pointer)). Calling `delete` on an uninitialized pointer, though (as you do here) isn't going to work.

Comment: If you want a "dynamic array" you should really be using [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). Then you can use [the rule of zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three#Rule_of_zero) and don't have to worry about these things.

Comment: Please avoid new/delete unless you have a reason for it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your copy constructor should not be attempting to delete the pointer array.  Since you are in the copy constructor and the array was never initialized in a member initialization list you can just use

```
Point::Point(const Point& p)
{
    coord = new int[2];
    coord[0] = p.coord[0];
    coord[1] = p.coord[1];
}
```

As [Ed Heal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/892256/ed-heal) pointed out there is no reason to even have any dynamic memory allocation in your class.  Your point class could simply be

```
class Point
{
private :
    int x;
    int y;
public:
    Point(int x_ = 0, int y_ = 0) : x(x_), y(y_) {}
    void printpoint() { std::cout << "Point (" << x << "," << y << ")\n"; }
};
```

Now we do not need a copy constructor or a destructor as the compiler provided ones will work just fine.

You are also deleting pointers that you never created with `new`.  `p5` points to `p1` so you cannot call `delete` on it.  Then you `delete` `p4` which is okay but when you `delete` `p6` which points to `p4` you are doing a double `delete` which is a big no no.

Comment: Will it be the deep copy constructor then? Because I need one here

Comment: There is nothing deep about it.

Comment: It still gives errors: http://pastie.org/private/oqdbbyljmbnrchuqfeeq. I changed my copy constructor to yours.

Comment: @BrianBrown: That is because you `delete` things you did not allocate. See for example `p5` and `p6`. You did not call `new` to allocate memory for them, yet you call `delete` on them. **DON'T** do this. Only call `delete` on things that have been `new`-ed.

Comment: This is not exactly true - delete is happy to delete on a null pointer.

Comment: @EdHeal: Yeah, I mentioned that above on the question itself; I meant don't call it on things that have been allocated on the stack (like `p5`), or on a pointer that is copied from another and the original pointer itself (like `p6` and `p4`).

Comment: @BrianBrown Added more to the answer.  You had some bad calls to delete in `main()`

Comment: Thank you all for your answers

Answer (score 3):

This is not an answer - but a bit too big for a comment.

Why not do this - a lot simpler:

```
class Point
{
private :
    int m_x, m_y;
public:
    Point() : m_x(0), m_y(0) {}
    Point(int x, int y) : m_x(x), m_y(y) {}
    Point(const Point& p) : m_x(p.m_x), m_y(p.m_y) {}
    ~Point() {}
    void printpoint() const {
        std::cout << "Point (" << m_x << "," << m_y << ")\n";
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you, I know that its simpler, I know. But I want to do it with array, and have some problems with copy constructor...

Comment: Why not `int coord[2]`? Why make a rod for your own back? Guess you like to make debugging harder for yourself