# c++ *& and null validation

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, dereference

Say I have the following function:

```
void destroy(Song* song) {
    if (song)
        delete song;
}
```

Can the implementation be changed to the following, to remove the null validation?

```
void destroy(Song*& song) {
    delete song;
}
```

If yes, why?

Comment: Using a pointer or a reference to a pointer makes no difference here.

Comment: @super - it does, a reference to pointer (2nd version) would not work if the original pointer is NULL

Comment: @artm It's perfectly fine and legal to make a reference to a `NULL`-pointer. A reference does not care about the value of the referenced object.

Comment: @artm Why wouldn't it? Look at emlai's answer.

Comment: @super ah, so you can't have a reference to NULL, but you can have a reference to a pointer to NULL.

Comment: @artm Not pointer-to-`NULL`, `NULL` represents a *null pointer value*. It is a *value* of a pointer variable, not something that it points to. You can form a rvalue reference to or `const` lvalue reference to `NULL`, just not a non-`const` lvalue reference, because `NULL` is a prvalue.

Comment: @artm You can have a `const reference` to a value. Since `NULL` is a value, you can actually have a reference to `NULL`. A reference must however refer to *something*, so in some sense you are right even if the wording is not.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to check for null, `delete` on a null pointer is valid and does nothing.

See [Is it safe to delete a NULL pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4190703/3425536)

---

If we assume `delete` on a null pointer would not be valid, then your second implementation of `destroy` wouldn't work, because the user can still do the following:

```
Song* p = nullptr;
destroy(p);
```

Answer (score 2):

From the C++ Standard (8.3.5 Delete)

> 2. ...In the ﬁrst alternative (delete object), **the value of the operand of
>      delete may be a null pointer value**, a pointer to a non-array object
>      created by a previous new-expression, or a pointer to a subobject
>      (4.5) representing a base class of such an object (Clause 13). If not,
>      the behavior is undeﬁned. **In the second alternative (delete array),
>      the value of the operand of delete may be a null pointer value** or a
>      pointer value that resulted from a previous array new-expression.83

Sp the check for a null-pointer is redundant. The same is valid for the C function `free`.