# Access violation exception from dump.Is there any way to see because of which variable it is happening?

Tags: c++, windbg, access-violation, dump

We are observing some sporadic issue in our customer site.
So we collected the dump and analysed using Winddbg.
From that we came to there was a Access Violation Exception .
The exact line is highlighted in the screen shot attached.
[image: Screen shot from Windbg]

Is there any way to check because of which pointer reference exception is occuring using windbg ?
I tried the locals window in Windbg also still  it did not help.
[image: locals window from WinDbg]

I tried Visual studio , and read a lot if there is a way , No luck :(

Thank you so much for time.

Edit 1 :

[image: r and ub command in Windbg]

Edit 2 :
[image: dt ModuleDef command result]

Comment: Dump the register state with `r`, dump the assembly for the currently executing code with `ub`. Correlate with your code, and inspect your variables with `dt`

Comment: Without knowing anything about your code I would guess that `ptModuleDef`is null, or `ptModuleDef->ptAssocDef` is null.

Comment: I suppose shipping a version with debug symbols would result in a core dump with symbol information?

Comment: @Botje i got the exact line from my code . But the variable i am not getting . Sry i am very new to windbg if i am asking silly questions.  I used the 3 commands as you said also . ptModuleDef is not NULL because  we have a check for that.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica We have the symbols and loaded the symbols also

Comment: Edit your question with the contents of the two commands I showed. It would also help if you included the output of `dt -r2 ptModuleDef` so we know its structure.

Comment: Please post code as text, not images.

Comment: I specifically asked for `dt`output because I wanted to know if `ptAssocDef` was at offset 0x15c from the start of your `ModuleDef` type. If you don't want to share that, please just do `dt ModuleDef`and see what its offset is. EDIT: I'm pretty certain `ptModuleDef->ptAssocDef` is null.

Comment: This is basic reverse-compiling. You need to understand assembly language if you're going to debug at this level. The `push [eax]` is probably the `apszFullSOPList[intCounter]` seeing as it's also the loop control and is probably already enregistered. This makes `mov eax, [esi+68h]` a load of something, and `push [eax+15ch]` a parameter. The other parameter is `intAssocID`, so working backward the push is probably the `->intAssocID`, which means that the `mov eax, [esi+68h]` is probably `ptModuleDef->ptAssocDef`. Since `eax` is zero in the crash dump, this means that `ptAssocDef` is null.

Comment: @Botje updated the question with dt command thank you

Comment: @RaymondChen Thank you . ptModuleDef->ptAssocDef is Null or is there any way it might have corrupted ?? I have this worry because we are doing   following code after this line . This is legacy code.                                                       if (ptModuleDef->ptAssocDef)
      {
         delete ptModuleDef->ptAssocDef; }

Comment: The value of hte `eax` register is right there in the debug output. `eax=00000000`.

Comment: `delete` on a NULL pointer is a no-op. Also, it happens *after* the crashing line, so it is not (yet) a concern.

Comment: To supplement @RaymondChen 's comment (should probably be an answer by itself): `ptAssocDef` is at offset 0x68, and your crash is trying to dereference the result of `[esi+68h]`.

Comment: @Botje and RaymondChen  The line where exception is happening ( Clear_Negotiation_Info(ptModuleDef->ptAssocDef->intAssocID,apszFullSOPList[intCounter]); ) , we are planning to remove this piece of code by using some other API's which dont use ptAssocDef. Then also it is necessary for me to  execute this piece                           if (ptModuleDef->ptAssocDef)
      {
         delete ptModuleDef->ptAssocDef;  
         ptModuleDef->ptAssocDef = NULL;   } i am worried it pointer is corrupted it might give some other issue . But if it is only Null then it wont cause any harm right ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190703/is-it-safe-to-delete-a-null-pointer

Comment: @RaymondChen thank you so much...

Comment: @Botje thank you so much..

Comment: in the ub esi+68 becomes 0 so you need to find out why