# NULL pointer and deleting it

Tags: c++, pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any reason to check for a NULL pointer before deleting ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/615355/is-there-any-reason-to-check-for-a-null-pointer-before-deleting)

Is there a bug in this code

```
Type * p = 0;
delete p;
```

`p` is a null pointer here. will there be any issues in implementing this.

Comment: `delete` is not a part of C. It is C++. Tag "c" changed to "c++"

Answer (score 4):

No, it's specified in the C++ specification that `delete` on a null pointer does nothing.

Comment: The OP has tagged the question [tag:c] not [tag:c++], but it still should be safe.

Comment: Well, I assumed that it was going about C++ because I saw delete, sorry. But I still think the OP meant C++.

Comment: _I KNOW_. That's why I think the OP meant C++ and not C.

Comment: Of course! It's been too long since I did any of this. Must remember to think before typing.

Comment: @nightcracker I was conforming what you said.