# How can I check if there is enough heap memory available?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, heap-memory

I have an assignment that requires me to create a "Heap" class that allocates and deallocates memory.  I believe that my code works and the solution builds and runs properly but I want to make sure that I am not getting any memory leaks.  I also need to add some code that checks if the desired amount to be allocated to the heap is even available...if someone were to allocate a very large amount.  How is it possible to check if the memory allocated on the heap is available or NULL if there is not enough memory.  Here is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Heap{
public:

double* allocateMemory(int memorySize)
{
    return new double[memorySize];
};
void deallocateMemory(double* dMemorySize)
{
    delete[] dMemorySize;
};

};

int main()
{
Heap heap;
cout << "Enter the number of double elements that you want to allocate: " << endl;
int hMemory;
const int doubleByteSize = 8;
cin >> hMemory;

double *chunkNew = heap.allocateMemory(hMemory);

cout << "The amount of space you took up on the heap is: " <<
         hMemory*doubleByteSize << " bytes" << 
     starting at address: " << "\n" << &hMemory << endl; 

heap.deallocateMemory(chunkNew);

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Consider using [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html) to check against memory leaks.

Comment: Please change 8 to sizeof(double)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not necessary to check beforehand, just try to allocate memory and if you can't, then catch the exception. In this case it is of type `bad_alloc`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <new>      // included for std::bad_alloc

/**
 * Allocates memory of size memorySize and returns pointer to it, or NULL if not enough memory.
 */
double* allocateMemory(int memorySize)
{
  double* tReturn = NULL;

  try
  {
     tReturn = new double[memorySize];
  }
  catch (bad_alloc& badAlloc)
  {
    cerr << "bad_alloc caught, not enough memory: " << badAlloc.what() << endl;
  }

  return tReturn;
};
```

### Important note

Be sure to guard against double-freeing memory. One way to do that would be to pass your pointer to `deallocateMemory` by reference, allowing the function to change the pointer value to `NULL`, thereby preventing the possibility of `delete`-ing the pointer twice.

```
void deallocateMemory(double* &dMemorySize)
{
   delete[] dMemorySize;
   dMemorySize = NULL; // Make sure memory doesn't point to anything.
};
```

This prevents problems like the following:

```
double *chunkNew = heap.allocateMemory(hMemory);
heap.deallocateMemory(chunkNew);
heap.deallocateMemory(chunkNew); // chunkNew has been freed twice!
```

Comment: Glad to help. Also, I updated the answer since you commented...there is an important note.

Comment: Actually... it is not necessary to check against `NULL` before deleting, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/615355/is-there-any-reason-to-check-for-a-null-pointer-before-deleting

Comment: My mistake, I meant to guard against a different problem: double-freeing. Answer has been edited.