# Check that the new array was successfully created

Tags: c++

I don't know a lot about C or C++ but I think with C when you create an array you use malloc to ask for the memory and then you check that the memory was allocated before assigning values. In C++ you implement an array using new instead. Would check the allocation of memory for the array in C++ the same as in C by checking that the array is not null?

For example,

```
int main()
{
      int* myArr = new int[10];
      if(myArr!=NULL)
      {
           //DO SOMETHING
      }
}
```

I get that most computers have a lot of memory, making running out of memory less likely today, but I also understand that failing to do things like this can lead to unexpected bugs later on down the road.

UPDATE: I was trying to keep my example simple. As mentioned in the comments I was referring to dynamic memory allocation. I am trying to implement a heap data structure. As part of the heap there exists an array to store the values of the heap. When the heap is full the array has to be expanded by design by the next power of 2. Thus i may initialize the heap as 10 but when I reach 10 I will need to expand to 16. Given enough items the heap will reach size 2^n. Therefore I am calling a function that has a parameter for the HEAP pointer. Then I create a new array and copy the values from the existing array to the new array. While doing this I was thinking about what happens if the new array cannot be created because of being out of memory. I may want to write the values to a file before exiting.

Comment: If `new` fails it throws an exception (unless you tell it otherwise).

Comment: Unless you use `std::nothrow`, operator `new` will, well, throw an exception if it doesn't have enough memory. The docs meniton it: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16158981/how-can-i-check-if-there-is-enough-heap-memory-available

Comment: @Galik Why are you answering in a comment?

Comment: Actually, in modern C++ you normally shouldn't mess with raw `new` and `delete`, and in case of arrays you should normally use `std::vector` instead.  (Or `std::array` if you're *absolutely* sure you know the size before-hand and there's no possibility you will ever need to adjust the size.)

Comment: Yes you must check whether operator `new` succeeded in allocating memory or not. `new` doesn't fail on allocating small number of elements but what about a huge program running for a long time and with a small memory space?

Comment: If an ordinary `new` expression fails it throws a `std::bad_alloc` exception. You can check for that by using a `try-catch`, but since memory exhaustion usually is a fatal condition it can be best to just propagate that exception all the way up to `main`, and terminate. Anyway, instead of a raw array allocated via a `new`-expression, for simplicity and safety just use a `std::vector`.

Comment: Don't use `new` and `delete`. Say, `std::vector myArr(10);` If all you can do if there's no memory available is to exit the program, you need do nothing else.

Comment: Based on your current edit, the suggestion of `std::vector` is even more applicable. It's smart, manages your memory for you, and resizes as required or on demand. The only reasons not to use `std::vector` are some neanderthal is demanding you not use it and you are writing your own vector implementation for educational purposes.

Comment: So with a vector can I have an array of defined structs?

Comment: `std::vector<mystruct> myvectorofmystruct(10);` just made 10 elements of `mystruct` for you. Mind you since you have added that the expansion requirements are quite strict, allowing vector to self-resize is not exactly what you want, but [that's what the `resize` method is for](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize).

Comment: Alright, thanks that helps.

Comment: If you need the array represented by the `vector` as an array to interact with something that demands a `mystruct *` [`std::vector::data` has that covered](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data).

Answer (score -2):

No, to make an array you do this:

```
int main()
{
   int myArr[10];
   // DO SOMETHING
}
```

If you *must* use dynamic allocation, use `new` without the `std::nothrow` specifier, so that it throws a `std::bad_alloc` exception if the allocation fails. That is ultimately the equivalent of checking for `malloc` returning a NULL pointer.

If you *do* use the `std::nothrow` specifier then, yes, check for a NULL pointer. In modern C++, that's `nullptr`. In antique C++, that's `NULL` (or `0`) as you've shown.

Comment: The OP means dynamic memory.

Comment: @Raindrop7: There is no reason to use dynamic memory for an array of 10 ints. That is the point.

Comment: The question could have just been trying to establish what would happen, rather than an example of actual code.

Comment: @Alexander: Then it was a poor example.

Comment: @Galik: It's not an array.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I think the way you worded your introduction sounds to me like you saying they have not correctly made an array. I see what you mean now but the OP might not get it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You may not have an 'array' typed identifier to access it through but it is still an array.

Comment: @Galik: Nah, the former disqualifies the latter in my view. You are of course free to disagree but that doesn't make this "incorrect".

Comment: lol at delete vote