# Why point a pointer to 0 after*** deleting it?

Tags: c++, pointers, null

I'm confused about why some people point a pointer (created on the heap earlier) to 0 *after* deleting it.

For example:

```
Node* newNode = new Node();

delete newNode;
newNode = 0;    // why?
```

Why does it matter if a deleted pointer points to 0 or to something else?

Comment: This is to act as a warning to anybody reading the code. It's a shorthand way of saying: "treat this code with extra care -- the author probably didn't know or understand RAII or else completely misunderstands object lifetime."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is done so that you'll get an immediate error if you ever accidentally try to use it after it's been deleted. Using a pointer that points to deleted memory may sometimes "work", but crash sometime later. By setting it to NULL, you make sure that it's always a bad pointer to use.

Comment: This is incorrect - delete 0; will always work - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/615355/is-there-any-reason-to-check-for-a-null-pointer-before-deleting or the spec.

Comment: @EdHeal: The answer is fine. It says `Using a pointer` not deleting a pointer.

Comment: @JesseGood - Delete a NULL pointer - No problem - it works

Comment: @EdHeal: **Using** a pointer encompasses more than just deleting it. hth

Comment: @JesseGood - Setting it to zero after deleting it means that if you inadvertently delete it again it is a noop.That was the trust of the question.

Comment: @EdHeal: The question said nothing about deleting it after setting it to NULL.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a pointer point it to `NULL` to make it invalid after deleting so that if you try to accidentally access it, you get an error.

**NOTE:** Earlier versions of compiler used `NULL`(which is practically #DEFINE NULL 0) to make pointer invalid. C++11 now has `nullptr` to make it invalid(which is different from `NULL`)

Answer (score 0):

So if further in the code you tried to delete it again you will not get an error.

Just a marker that you have done it!